# Number Plate Golf: Recognition

Tags: code-golf, image-processing, optical-char-recognition

**See also: [Parsing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/90333/number-plate-golf-parsing)**

### Introduction

You're working on a government programming team, who have been programming the speed cameras. However, the group of people who have programmed the speed calculator have taken up too much space, so you have to make the number plate recognition software as small as possible.

### Challenge

Given an image of a number plate, return the text on the plate.

### Number plates

The following are all of the characters which your program must recognise:

#### ABCDEFG

[image]

#### H1JKLMN0

[image]

#### PQRSTUVW

[image]

#### XYZ01234

[image]

#### 56789

[image]

#### Note

On British number plates, the characters for I (i) and 1 (one) are the same and the characters for O (o) and 0 (zero) are the same. For that reason, always assume characters are the numbers. I.e. the following number plate is 10 (one zero):

[image]

### Examples

#### C0D3 GLF

[image]

#### B3T4 DCY

[image]

#### M1NUS 15

[image]

#### YET1CGN

[image]

### Other rules

Internet access and OCR libraries and functions are disallowed.

The number plates will always look identical to the ones shown above. All number plates will be roughly same size (there will be some inaccuracies due to cropping method).

If you require lossless PNG versions of any number plates, I will supply them to you.

### Scoring

The shortest program in bytes wins.

<sub>**All number plates are screenshots of the search bar at [this site](http://www.click4reg.co.uk)**</sub>

Comment: identical, byte to byte?

Comment: @YOU I don't understand the question...

Comment: Remind me to drive through your speed trap. (My number plate contains a letter O.)

Comment: I asked with the hope of without having to parse images to understand characters, like pattern matching some location of image binaries, nevermind. I actually don't have any clue how to match them.

Comment: yes, beta, your 0 and O are exactly the same.....

Comment: yes, @tuskiomi, they are.....

Comment: Can we expect any scaling, rotation, skewing, shading, or light letters on dark?

Comment: @YiminRong No, all number plates will be exactly the same as those in the images in the question

Comment: are all of the images the exact same size?

Comment: You should add "OCR" or something like that to the title of the challenge so people know what it's about.

Comment: Yes, this question's title is pretty inaccurate. How about *"OCR a British license plate"*?

Comment: @Neil My UK number plate has both an O and a 0 and they look identical. There are of course rules to determine which is the correct interpretation, but that would be a whole other challenge.

Comment: @LevelRiverSt Indeed, I was thinking of posting it to the Sandbox myself.

Comment: It's too bad the characters aren't a fixed width. That could make for some very short code possibilities.

Comment: I'd like to have http://i.imgur.com/i8jkCJu.png added to the test cases, if that's possible. ;-)

Comment: @YetiCGN Your wish is my command ;)

Comment: Thanks! Now I know why they are called "vanity plates". :-D

Comment: Do we have to include spaces in our output or is returning just the letters (in order) enough?

Comment: @Dave No, spaces are not needed

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## C, 409 bytes (and I'm as surprised as anybody)

```c
f(w,h,d,X,T,B,x,y,b,v,u,t,a)char*d;{for(x=X=0;++x<w;){for(y=b=h;y--;a=0)d[(y*w+x)*3+1]&224||(b=0,X||(X=x,T=B=y),T=y<T?y:T,B=y>B?y:B);if(X*b){for(B+=1-T,X=x-X,v=5;v--;)for(u=4;u--;a|=(b>X/4*(B/5)*.35)<<19-u*5-v)for(b=0,t=X/4;t--;)for(y=B/5;y--;)b+=!(d[((v*B/5+y+T)*w+x-X+u*X/4+t)*3+1]&224);X=!putchar("g------a----mj---et-u--6----7--8s4-c-x--q--d9xy5-0v--n-2-hw-k-----3---bf-----t-r---pzn-1---l"[a%101-7]);}}}
```

Takes as input: the width (`w`) and height (`h`) of the image, followed by the packed RGB data as an array of `char`s (`d`). All the other function parameters are variable declarations in disguise. Ignores everything except the green channel, and applies a threshold of 32 as an initial pass.

Mostly the same as @DavidC's method, except this checks that at least 35% of each sample box is filled. Hopefully that makes it more robust to scale changes, but who knows.

I used a brute-force method to find out which resampling size and coverage percent to use for the best reliability (i.e. fewest cases of one character having multiple interpretations). It turned out that a 4x5 grid with 35% coverage was best. I then used a second brute-force method to calculate the best bit arrangement and modulo value to pack the character data into a short string — the low bit at the top-left, increasing in x then y, with the final value % 101 turned out best, giving this lookup table:

```
-------g------a----mj---et-u--6----7--8s4-c-x--q--d9xy5-0v--n-2-hw-k-----3---bf-----t-r---pzn-1---l--
```

Subtracting 7 means the initial -'s can be removed, and the last 2 can be removed without any extra work. This removal means that certain invalid inputs could cause an invalid memory read, so it could segfault on particular images.

#### Usage:

To get the images into it, I wrote a wrapper using libpng. Also it turns out that despite the filename, the images in the question are actually jpegs (!), so you'll need to manually export them as pngs first.

```c
#include <png.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, const char *const *argv) {
    if(argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <file.png>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    const char *file = argv[1];

    FILE *const fp = fopen(file, "rb");
    if(fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open %s for reading\n", file);
        return 1;
    }

    png_structp png_ptr = png_create_read_struct(
        PNG_LIBPNG_VER_STRING, NULL, NULL, NULL
    );

    if(!png_ptr) {
        fclose(fp);
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialise LibPNG (A)\n");
        return 1;
    }

    png_infop info_ptr = png_create_info_struct(png_ptr);

    if(!info_ptr) {
        png_destroy_read_struct(&png_ptr, NULL, NULL);
        fclose(fp);
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialise LibPNG (B)\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if(setjmp(png_jmpbuf(png_ptr))) {
        png_destroy_read_struct(&png_ptr, &info_ptr, NULL);
        fclose(fp);
        fprintf(stderr, "Error while reading PNG\n");
        return 1;
    }

    png_init_io(png_ptr, fp);
    png_set_sig_bytes(png_ptr, 0);

    png_read_png(
        png_ptr, info_ptr,
        PNG_TRANSFORM_STRIP_16 |
        PNG_TRANSFORM_GRAY_TO_RGB |
        PNG_TRANSFORM_STRIP_ALPHA,
        NULL
    );
    const png_bytep *const rows = png_get_rows(png_ptr, info_ptr);
    const int w = png_get_image_width(png_ptr, info_ptr);
    const int h = png_get_image_height(png_ptr, info_ptr);
    unsigned char *const data = malloc(w*h*3 * sizeof(unsigned char));
    for(int y = 0; y < h; ++ y) {
        for(int x = 0; x < w; ++ x) {
            memcpy(&data[y*w*3], rows[y], w * 3 * sizeof(unsigned char));
        }
    }
    png_destroy_read_struct(&png_ptr, &info_ptr, NULL);
    fclose(fp);

    f(w, h, (char*) data);

    free(data);

    return 0;
}
```

#### Breakdown

```c
f(                          // Function
    w,h,d,                  // Parameters: width, height, RGB data
    X,T,B,x,y,b,v,u,t,a     // Variables
)char*d;{                   // K&R syntax to save lots of type decls
  for(x=X=0;++x<w;){        // Loop through each column of the image:
    for(y=b=h;y--;a=0)      //  Loop through pixels in column:
      d[(y*w+x)*3+1]&224||( //   If green < 32: (char could be signed or unsigned)
        b=0,                //    This is not a blank line
        X||(X=x,T=B=y),     //    Start a new character if not already in one
        T=y<T?y:T,          //    Record top of character
        B=y>B?y:B           //    Record bottom of character
      );
    if(X*b){                //  If we just found the end of a character:
      // Check cell grid & record bits into "a"
      for(B+=1-T,X=x-X,v=5;v--;)
        for(u=4;u--;a|=(b>X/4*(B/5)*.35)<<19-u*5-v)
          // Calculate coverage of current cell
          for(b=0,t=X/4;t--;)
            for(y=B/5;y--;)
              b+=!(d[((v*B/5+y+T)*w+x-X+u*X/4+t)*3+1]&224);

      // Look up meaning of "a" in table & print, reset X to 0
      X=!putchar(
        "g------a----mj---et-u--6----7--8s4-c-x--q--d9x"
        "y5-0v--n-2-hw-k-----3---bf-----t-r---pzn-1---l"
        [a%101-7]
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 for beating Python and Mathemetica with freaking *C*. Oooollllld school, yo.

Comment: +1 for WINNING with C, like, never thought that could happen, huh

Answer (score 11):

## Mathematica <s>1170 1270 1096 1059 650 528 570 551 525</s> 498 bytes

The latest version saves 27 bytes by not requiring that the plate be "trimmed" before it is parsed.  The penultimate version saved 26 bytes by using only 10 of the original 24 sample points.

```
z=Partition;h@i_:=i~PixelValue~#/.{_,_,_,z_}:>⌈z⌉&/@z[{45,99,27,81,63,81,9,63,45,63,9,45,45,45,63,45,45,27,45,9},2];f@p_:=h/@SortBy[Select[p~ColorReplace~Yellow~ComponentMeasurements~{"Image","Centroid"},100<Last@ImageDimensions@#[[2,1]]<120&],#[[2,2,1]]&][[All,2,1]]/.Thread[IntegerDigits[#,2,10]&/@(z[IntegerDigits[Subscript["ekqeuiv5pa5rsebjlic4i5886qsmvy34z5vu4e7nlg9qqe3g0p8hcioom6qrrkzv4k7c9fdc3shsm1cij7jrluo", "36"]],4]/.{a__Integer}:> FromDigits[{a}])-> Characters@"BD54TARP89Q0723Z6EFGCSWMNVYXHUJKL1"]
```

---

122 bytes saved through LegionMammal978's idea of packing the long list of base 10 numbers as a single, base 36 number.  He pared another 20 bytes off the final code.

The jump from 528 to 570 bytes was due to additional code to ensure that the order of the letters returned corresponded to the order of the letters on the license plate. The centroid for each letter contains the x-coordinate, which reveals the relative positions of the letters along x.

---

**Ungolfed Code**

```
coordinates=Flatten[Table[{x,y},{y,99,0,-18},{x,9,72,18}],1];
h[img_] :=ArrayReshape[PixelValue[img, #] /. {_, _, _, z_} :>  ⌈z⌉  & /@ coordinates, {6, 4}];
plateCrop[img_]:=ColorReplace[ImageTrim[img,{{100,53},{830,160}}],Yellow];
codes={{{15,13,15,13,13,15},"B"},{{15,8,8,8,9,15},"C"},{{15,13,13,13,13,15},"D"},{{15,8,14,8,8,15},"E"},{{15,8,14,8,8,8},"F"},{{15,8,8,11,9,15},"G"},{{6,6,6,6,15,9},"A"},{{9,9,15,15,9,9},"H"},{{8,8,8,8,8,15},"L"},{{9,15,15,15,13,9},"M"},{{15,9,9,9,9,15},"0"},{{9,10,12,14,10,9},"K"},{{9,13,13,11,11,9},"N"},{{8,8,8,8,8,8},"1"},{{1,1,1,1,9,15},"J"},{{15,9,15,14,8,8},"P"},{{15,9,9,9,15,15},"Q"},{{15,9,15,14,10,11},"R"},{{15,8,12,3,1,15},"S"},{{9,15,6,6,6,6},"V"},{{15,6,6,6,6,6},"T"},{{9,15,15,15,15,15},"W"},{{9,9,9,9,9,15},"U"},{{9,14,6,6,14,9},"X"},{{9,14,6,6,6,6},"Y"},{{15,3,2,4,12,15},"Z"},{{15,9,9,9,9,15},"0"},{{8,8,8,8,8,8},"1"},{{15,1,3,6,12,15},"2"},{{15,1,3,1,9,15},"3"},{{2,6,6,15,2,2},"4"},{{7,12,14,1,1,15},"5"},{{15,8,14,9,9,15},"6"},{{15,1,2,2,6,4},"7"},{{15,9,15,9,9,15},"8"},{{15,9,15,1,9,15},"9"}};
decryptRules=Rule@@@codes;
isolateLetters[img_]:=SortBy[Select[ComponentMeasurements[plateCrop[img],{"Image","Centroid"}],ImageDimensions[#[[2,1]]][[2]]>100&],#[[2,2,1]]&][[All,2,1]]
f[plate_]:=FromDigits[#,2]&/@#&/@h/@isolateLetters[plate]/.decryptRules
```

**Overview**

The basic idea is to check whether a systematic sampling of pixels from the input image matches pixels from the same location on the bonafide images.  Much of the code consists of the bit signatures for each character,

The diagram shows the pixels that are sampled from the letters "J", "P","Q", and "R".

[image: jpqr]

The pixel values can be represented as matrices. The dark, bold `1`'s correspond to black cells. The `0`'s correspond to white cells.

[image: jjjj]

These are the decryption replacement rules for J  P  Q  R.

{1, 1, 1, 1, 9, 15} -> "J",
{15, 9, 15, 14, 8, 8} -> "P",
{15, 9, 9, 9, 15, 15} -> "Q",
{15, 9, 15, 14, 10, 11} -> "R"

It should be possible to understand why the rule for "0" is:

{15, 9, 9, 9, 9, 15} -> "0"

and thus distinguishable from the letter "Q".

---

The following shows the 10 points used in the final version.  These points are sufficient for identifying all of the characters.

[image: reduced]

---

**What the functions do**

`plateCrop[img]` removes the frame and left edge from the plate, makes the background white.  I was able to eliminate this function from the final version by selecting image components, possible letters  that were between 100 and 120 pixels high.

[image: platecrop]

---

`isolateLetters[img]` removes the individual letters from the cropped image.

We can display how it works by showing where the cropped image, output from `plateCrop` goes as input for `isolateLetters`. The output is a *list* of individual characters.

[image: letters]

---

`Coordinates` are 24 evenly distributed positions for checking the pixel color. The coordinates correspond to those in the first figure.

```
coordinates=Flatten[Table[{x,y},{y,99,0,-18},{x,9,72,18}],1];
```

{{9, 99}, {27, 99}, {45, 99}, {63, 99}, {9, 81}, {27, 81}, {45, 
  81}, {63, 81}, {9, 63}, {27, 63}, {45, 63}, {63, 63}, {9, 45}, {27, 
  45}, {45, 45}, {63, 45}, {9, 27}, {27, 27}, {45, 27}, {63, 27}, {9, 
  9}, {27, 9}, {45, 9}, {63, 9}}

---

`h` converts the pixels to binary.

```
h[img_] :=ArrayReshape[PixelValue[img, #] /. {_, _, _, z_} :>  ⌈z⌉  & /@ coordinates, {6, 4}];
```

---

`codes` are the signature for each character.  The decimal values are abbreviations of the binary code for black (0) and White (1) cells. In the golfed version, base 36 is used.

```
codes={{{15, 9, 9, 9, 9, 15}, "0"}, {{8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8}, "1"}, {{15, 1, 3,6,12, 15}, "2"}, {{15, 1, 3, 1, 9, 15}, "3"}, {{2, 6, 6, 15, 2, 2}, "4"}, {{7, 12, 14, 1, 1, 15},"5"}, {{15, 8, 14, 9, 9, 15}, "6"}, {{15, 1, 2, 2, 6, 4},"7"}, {{15, 9, 15, 9, 9, 15}, "8"}, {{15, 9, 15, 1, 9, 15},"9"}, {{6, 6, 6, 6, 15, 9}, "A"}, {{15, 13, 15, 13, 13, 15}, "B"}, {{15, 8, 8, 8, 9, 15}, "C"}, {{15, 13, 13, 13, 13, 15}, "D"}, {{15, 8, 14, 8, 8, 15}, "E"}, {{15, 8, 14, 8, 8, 8},"F"}, {{15, 8, 8, 11, 9, 15}, "G"}, {{9, 9, 15, 15, 9, 9}, "H"}, {{1, 1, 1, 1, 9, 15}, "J"}, {{9, 10, 12, 14, 10, 9}, "K"}, {{8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 15}, "L"}, {{9, 15, 15, 15, 13, 9}, "M"}, {{9, 13, 13, 11, 11, 9}, "N"}, {{15, 9, 15, 14, 8, 8}, "P"}, {{15, 9, 9, 9, 15, 15}, "Q"}, {{15, 9, 15, 14, 10, 11}, "R"}, {{15, 8, 12, 3, 1, 15}, "S"}, {{15, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6}, "T"}, {{9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 15}, "U"}, {{9, 15, 6, 6, 6, 6}, "V"}, {{9, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15}, "W"}, {{9, 14, 6, 6, 14, 9}, "X"}, {{9, 14, 6, 6, 6, 6}, "Y"}, {{15, 3, 2, 4, 12, 15}, "Z"}};
```

(* `decryptRules` are for replacing signatures with their respective character *)

```
decryptRules=Rule@@@codes;
```

`f` is the function that takes an image of a license plate and returns a letter.

```
f[plate_]:=FromDigits[#,2]&/@#&/@h/@isolate[plateCrop@plate]/.decryptRules;
```

[image: plates]

{"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"}
{"H", "1", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "0"}
{"P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W"}
{"X", "Y", "Z", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4"}
{"5", "6", "7", "8", "9"}

---

### Golfed

The code is shortened by using a single decimal number to represent all 24 bits (white or black) for each character. For example, the letter "J" uses the following replacement rule: `1118623 -> "J"`.

1118623 corresponds to

```
IntegerDigits[1118623 , 2, 24]
```

{0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1,
  1}

which can be repackaged as

```
ArrayReshape[{0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {6, 4}]
```

{{0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 
  1}, {1, 1, 1, 1}}

which is simply the matrix for "J" that we saw above.

```
%//MatrixForm
```

[image: matrix]

Another savings comes from representing the alphabet as `"0123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ"` rather than as a list of letters.

Finally, all of the functions from the long version, except `h`, were integrated into the function `f` rather than defined separately.

---

```
h@i_:=ArrayReshape[i~PixelValue~#/.{_,_,_,z_}:>⌈z⌉&/@Join@@Table[{x,y},{y,99,0,-18},{x,9,72,18}],{6,4}];f@p_:=#~FromDigits~2&/@(Join@@@h/@SortBy[Select[p~ImageTrim~{{100,53},{830,160}}~ColorReplace~Yellow~ComponentMeasurements~{"Image","Centroid"},Last@ImageDimensions@#[[2,1]]>100&],#[[2,2,1]]&][[;;,2,1]])/.Thread[IntegerDigits[36^^1c01agxiuxom9ds3c3cskcp0esglxf68g235g1d27jethy2e1lbttwk1xj6yf590oin0ny1r45wc1i6yu68zxnm2jnb8vkkjc5yu06t05l0xnqhw9oi2lwvzd5f6lsvsb4izs1kse3xvx694zwxz007pnj8f6n,8^8]->Characters@"J4A51LUHKNYXVMW732ZTCGSFE60Q98PRDB"]
```

Comment: @DavidC Seems like SE messed it up; try replacing `{1118623, 2518818, ..., 16645599}` with [this](http://pastebin.com/NW7k9W3j).

Comment: @LegionMammal978, your suggestion led to a shortening of the code by over 100 bytes.  I now understand better how Mathematica handles bases.

Comment: @DavidC Also, it appears as if some whitespace snuck through to your golfed code, and I count 571 bytes without it. Additionally, some functions can be converted to infix form. `x[[All,2,1]]` can be replaced with `x[[;;,2,1]]`. `Flatten[x,1]` is equivalent to `Join@@x`, and `Flatten[#,1]&/@x` is equivalent to `Join@@@x`. There are a few other minor optimizations that can be done. [The 551-byte code after these golfs.](http://pastebin.com/PYQnr30M)

Comment: Nice tips and careful reading. Thanks.

Comment: Did you attempt to minimize the number of sampling points by moving them around?

Comment: Not by moving them around, but instead by using key sampling points to "divide and conquer".  5 bits or points are sufficient to uniquely identify, say, half of the characters.  At least 5 more bits would probably be sufficient for all.  This would likely save some space, but I'm not inclined to follow it through.

Comment: I was able to find 12 sampling points that are sufficient for distinguishing, hence identifying, all of the 36 characters.

Answer (score 4):

### C#, <s>1040</s> 1027 bytes

```
using System;using System.Drawing;class _{static Bitmap i;static bool b(int x,int y)=>i.GetPixel(x,y).GetBrightness()<.4;static char l(int x,int y){if(y<45)return b(x+5,145)?((b(x+30,100)||b(x+30,50))?(b(x+68,94)?(b(x+40,50)?'D':b(x+40,120)?(b(x+45,80)?'M':'N'):'H'):b(x,97)?(b(x+30,140)?'E':b(x+60,70)?(b(x+50,140)?'R':'P'):'F'):b(x+65,45)?(b(x+5,100)?'K':b(x+30,145)?'Z':'X'):'B'):b(x+30,140)?'L':'1'):b(x+30,55)?(b(x+60,70)?'7':'T'):b(x+2,100)?'U':b(x+30,70)?'W':b(x+15,100)?'V':'Y';if(y<70)return b(x+50,110)?(b(x+50,70)?(b(x+10,110)?(b(x+30,100)?(b(x+55,80)?'8':'6'):b(x+55,80)?'0':'G'):b(x+10,70)?(b(x+60,80)?'9':'S'):b(x+60,120)?'3':'2'):'G'):b(x+30,125)?'Q':'C';if(y>150)return'A';if(y>120)return'J';else return b(x+10,135)?'5':'4';}static void Main(string[]z){i=new Bitmap(Console.ReadLine());bool s=true;int w=int.MinValue;for(int x=100;x<800;++x){for(int y=40;y<160;++y)if(s){if(b(x,y)){if(w>50)Console.Write(' ');Console.Write(l(x,y));s=false;goto e;}}else if(b(x,y))goto e;if(!s){s=true;w=0;}else++w;e:continue;}}}
```

Ungolfed:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;

class _
{
    static Bitmap bmp;
    static bool b(int x, int y) => bmp.GetPixel(x, y).GetBrightness() < .4;
    static char l(int x, int y)
    {
        if (y < 45)
            return b(x + 5, 145) ? ((b(x + 30, 100) || b(x + 30, 50)) ? (b(x + 68, 94) ? (b(x + 40, 50) ? 'D' : b(x + 40, 120) ? (b(x + 45, 80) ? 'M' : 'N') : 'H') : b(x, 97) ? (b(x + 30, 140) ? 'E' : b(x + 60, 70) ? (b(x + 50, 140) ? 'R' : 'P') : 'F') : b(x + 65, 45) ? (b(x + 5, 100) ? 'K' : b(x + 30, 145) ? 'Z' : 'X') : 'B') : b(x + 30, 140) ? 'L' : '1') : b(x + 30, 55) ? (b(x + 60, 70) ? '7' : 'T') : b(x + 2, 100) ? 'U' : b(x + 30, 70) ? 'W' : b(x + 15, 100) ? 'V' : 'Y';
        if (y < 70)
            return b(x + 50, 110) ? (b(x + 50, 70) ? (b(x + 10, 110) ? (b(x + 30, 100) ? (b(x + 55, 80) ? '8' : '6') : b(x + 55, 80) ? '0' : 'G') : b(x + 10, 70) ? (b(x + 60, 80) ? '9' : 'S') : b(x + 60, 120) ? '3' : '2') : 'G') : b(x + 30, 125) ? 'Q' : 'C';
        if (y > 150)
            return 'A';
        if (y > 120)
            return 'J';
        if (y > 95)
            return b(x + 10, 135) ? '5' : '4';
        return '-';
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bmp = new Bitmap(Console.ReadLine());
        bool state = true;
        int space = int.MinValue;
        for (int x = 100; x < 800; ++x)
        {
            for (int y = 40; y < 160; ++y)
                if (state)
                {
                    if (b(x, y))
                    {
                        if (space > 50)
                            Console.Write(' ');
                        Console.Write(l(x, y));
                        state = false;
                        goto bad;
                    }
                }
                else if (b(x, y))
                    goto bad;
            if (!state)
            {
                state = true;
                space = 0;
            }
            else
                ++space;
            bad:
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

Basically I found some specific reference points to check yellow/black to determine the identity of each character.

Comment: Are you sure there is no overfit to the images provided and that it will recognize license plates where the characters are e.g. shifted by 10 pixels?

Comment: @YetiCGN it should recognize it so long as the size is the same, and they are in the same vertical position. I have tried with all the provided examples, and it works; please let me know if you find one where it doesn't

Comment: I don't want to install Visual Studio just for this, but you can try http://i.imgur.com/i8jkCJu.png which is a bit smaller in size. I think it's safe to assume that all the submissions will be images from that particular website. Initially my comment was more along the lines of "what if it's a real plate scan?" / "what if somebody else shifted all the characters vertically by 10 pixels to make a plate?"

Comment: @YetiCGN you shouldn't need VisualStudio to compile, just `csc.exe main.cs /r:System.Drawing.dll`

Answer (score 2):

## PHP – <s>1741</s> <s>1674</s> 1143 bytes

It was first set up by learning the profiles of the characters from the first few examples, which then summarized each character into six numbers. I chose six because I originally had five, and it didn't work as great as I'd like, but six seems to work much better. Much of the optimization involves squeezing these profiles into smaller and smaller byte counts.

The first and second profile `*lhdfdn` and `|nnmmkk` are actually the blue blob with "GB" at the bottom `*`, and the right border `|`, which we're ignoring. It's safer to include them so that the blob and right border have something to match against.

Should handle any image format, any reasonable scaling provided the aspect ratio doesn't change too much, any dark on light color, and even a bit of noise and shading!

It does need the border, at least at the top and bottom, that's part of the profile.

```
<?php $X=[];foreach(str_split('*lhdfdn|nnmmkkA<njjk;BOnKB`^Chn::E7DHn?1X`EnkGGD4Fn_330!Gnj9G[IHnX!!XnJ%(##knKnX.EN6LnX!!!!Mn_<:bnNn^77_nPn^33@6QhfBDjnRn_8LaDSOlYYnUT$$nn$$Uh_##^nV9c][n;W_nWTlhXHnLTiCY4LhnM5ZJbnmaI0ng88lk1nnnnnn2C[__n`34B?Kna4+=Fnb"5NnUReX6gnKKaM7*4Xnb=8gkIIne9K`KKni',7)as$s){$t=[];foreach(str_split(substr($s,1))as$u)$t[]=ord($u)-11;$X[$s[0]]=$t;}echo m(r($argv[1]),$X)."\n";function r($u){$a=[];$i=imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($u));$w=imagesx($i);$h=imagesy($i);$s=[];for($x=0;$x<$w;$x++){$s[$x]=0;for($y=0;$y<$h;$y++){$p=imagecolorsforindex($i,imagecolorat($i,$x,$y));if(3*$p['red']+6*$p['green']+$p['blue']<1280)$s[$x]++;}}$j=0;$k=[];for($x=0;$x<$w;$x++){if($s[$x]>$h/10)for($o=0;$o<6;$o++)$k[]=$s[$x];elseif(count($k)){$a[]=$k;$j++;$k=[];}}$b=[];foreach($a as$v){$t=[];$u=array_chunk($v,intval(count($v)/6));foreach($u as$c)$t[]=array_sum($c)/count($c);$m=99/max($t);$e=[];foreach($t as$x)$e[]=intval($x*$m+0.5);$b[]=$e;}return$b;}function m($A,$X){$r='';foreach($A as$a){$s=INF;$c='';foreach($X as$k=>$x){$t=0;for($i=0;$i<6;$i++)$t+=pow($a[$i]-$x[$i],2);if($s>$t){$s=$t;$c=$k;}}$r.=$c;}return trim($r,'|*');}
```

Save as `ocr.php`, then run from the command line:

```
$ php ocr.php http://i.imgur.com/UfI63md.png
ABCDEFG

$ php ocr.php http://i.imgur.com/oSAK7dy.png
H1JKLMN0

$ php ocr.php http://i.imgur.com/inuIHjm.png
PQRSTUVW

$ php ocr.php http://i.imgur.com/Th0QkhT.png
XYZ01234

$ php ocr.php http://i.imgur.com/igH3ZPQ.png
56789

$ php ocr.php http://i.imgur.com/YfVwebo.png
10

$ php ocr.php http://i.imgur.com/3ibQARb.png
C0D3GLF

$ php ocr.php http://i.imgur.com/c7XZqhL.png
B3T4DCY

$ php ocr.php http://i.imgur.com/ysBgXhn.png
M1NUS15
```

For those that are interested, here is the learning code. Save as `learn.php` and run from the command line, no arguments.

```
<?php

define('BANDS', 6);

main();

function main()
{
    $glyphs = [];

    learn($glyphs, 'http://imgur.com/UfI63md.png', '*ABCDEFG|');
    learn($glyphs, 'http://imgur.com/oSAK7dy.png', '*H1JKLMN0|');
    learn($glyphs, 'http://imgur.com/inuIHjm.png', '*PQRSTUVW|');
    learn($glyphs, 'http://imgur.com/Th0QkhT.png', '*XYZ01234|');
    learn($glyphs, 'http://imgur.com/igH3ZPQ.png', '*56789|');

    $profiles = summarize($glyphs);

    foreach ($profiles as $glyph=>$profile)
    {
        print $glyph;
        foreach ($profile as $value)
            print chr($value + 11);
        print "\n";
    }
}

function learn(&$glyphs, $url, $answer)
{
    $image = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($url));
    $width = imagesx($image);
    $height = imagesy($image);
    $counts = [];
    for ($x = 0; $x < $width; $x++)
    {
        $counts[$x] = 0;
        for ($y = 0; $y < $height; $y++)
        {
            $pixel = imagecolorsforindex($image, imagecolorat($image, $x, $y));
            if (3 * $pixel['red'] + 6 * $pixel['green'] + $pixel['blue'] < 1280)
                $counts[$x]++;
        }
    }

    $index = 0;
    $expanded = [];
    for ($x = 0; $x < $width; $x++)
    {
        if ($counts[$x] > $height / 10)
            for ($inner = 0; $inner < BANDS; $inner++)
                $expanded[] = $counts[$x];
        else if (count($expanded)) {
            $glyphs[$answer[$index]] = $expanded;
            $index++;
            $expanded = [];
        }
    }
}

function summarize($glyphs)
{
    $profiles = [];
    foreach ($glyphs as $glyph=>$expanded)
    {
        $averages = [];
        $bands = array_chunk($expanded, count($expanded) / BANDS);
        foreach ($bands as $band)
            $averages[] = array_sum($band) / count($band);
        $scaling = 99 / max($averages);
        $profile = [];
        foreach ($averages as $average)
            $profile[] = intval($average * $scaling + 0.5);
        $profiles[$glyph] = $profile;
    }
    return $profiles;
}

?>
```

Comment: You should include the spaces in the output

Comment: That's not in the specs under *The following are all of the characters which your program must recognise*, just characters A-H, J-N, P-Z, and 0-9. No mention of spaces.

Comment: Oh, okay, yours is fine then

Comment: "The first and second profile [...] are actually the blue blob with "GB" at the bottom, and the right border, which we're ignoring." Then why did you include them in the code, especially if the array key with an empty string is overwritten? Plus: It is allowed to use short open syntax for code golf! :-)

Comment: @YetiCGN - if they aren't then the code will attempt to match them to something else! I didn't realize they were overwritten, lucky the code still worked. Revising. You might be able to adapt some of my changes to your answer.

Comment: True, I found that one of them needs to be there during testing, but barely had enough free time to finish my answer. Nice rewrite, by the way!

Comment: You can save even more when you use unique variables for loops and omit the initialization: `for(;$i<$w;$i++)`. `pow` can be replaced by the [`**` operator since PHP 5.6](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) and because Notices are ignored by default, strings can be written as constants without the quotation marks.

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, <s>971</s> 970 bytes

Draws heavily upon [Yimin Rong](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/15259/yimin-rong)'s [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/90308/58556), which can be seriously golfed down, especially the array indices, and put into a Phar with gzip compression.

[Download the phar](http://mehr.it/golf/ocr.phar)

This is my improved base version at <s>1557</s> 1535 bytes, saved simply under the filename "o":

```
<?$X=[[99,92,45,45,97,96],[99,99,99,99,99,99],[56,80,84,84,99,85],[41,55,52,64,99,86],[32,50,59,99,87,23],[67,99,74,71,90,77],[92,99,64,64,86,66],[31,41,77,99,87,50],[92,96,62,62,99,90],[64,85,64,64,99,94],''=>[99,99,98,98,96,96],A=>[49,99,95,95,96,48],B=>[68,99,64,55,85,83],C=>[93,99,47,47,58,44],D=>[61,99,52,38,77,85],E=>[99,96,60,60,57,41],F=>[99,84,40,40,37,22],G=>[99,95,46,60,80,62],H=>[99,77,22,22,77,99],1=>[99,99,99,99,99,99],J=>[26,29,24,24,96,99],K=>[99,77,35,58,67,43],L=>[99,77,22,22,22,22],M=>[99,84,49,47,87,99],N=>[99,83,44,44,84,99],P=>[99,83,40,40,53,43],Q=>[93,91,55,57,95,99],R=>[99,84,45,65,86,57],S=>[68,97,78,78,99,74],T=>[25,25,99,99,25,25],U=>[93,84,24,24,83,99],V=>[46,88,82,80,99,48],W=>[84,99,76,73,97,93],X=>[61,99,65,73,94,56],Y=>[41,65,93,99,66,42],Z=>[63,87,99,98,86,62]];echo m(r($argv[1]),$X);function r($u){$a=[];$i=imagecreatefromstring(join('',file($u)));$w=imagesx($i);$h=imagesy($i);$s=[];for(;$x<$w;$x++){$s[$x]=0;for($y=0;$y<$h;$y++){$p=imagecolorsforindex($i,imagecolorat($i,$x,$y));if(3*$p[red]+6*$p[green]+$p[blue]<1280)$s[$x]++;}}$j=0;$k=[];for(;$z<$w;$z++){if($s[$z]>$h/10)for($o=0;$o<6;$o++)$k[]=$s[$z];elseif(count($k)){$a[]=$k;$j++;$k=[];}}$b=[];foreach($a as$v){$t=[];$u=array_chunk($v,~~(count($v)/6));foreach($u as$c)$t[]=array_sum($c)/count($c);$m=99/max($t);$e=[];foreach($t as$x)$e[]=~~($x*$m+.5);$b[]=$e;}return$b;}function m($A,$X){$r='';foreach($A as$a){$s=INF;$c='';foreach($X as$k=>$x){$t=0;for($i=0;$i<6;)$t+=($a[$i]-$x[$i++])**2;if($s>$t){$s=$t;$c=$k;}}$r.=$c;}return$r;}
```

### Improvements:

1st stage

- Numeric array indices removed and reordered the array, string indices as implicit constants

2nd stage

- Replaced `intval` with `~~` (saves 8 bytes, two occurences)
- for-loop initialization removed where unnecessary
- `file_get_contents($u)` replaced with `join('',file($u))` (saves 5 bytes)
- and a few others

Unfortunately, all the second stage improvements only translate into 1 byte less gzipped code. :-D

And this code was used to create the Phar:

```
<?php
$phar = new Phar('o.phar');
$phar->addFile('o');
$phar['o']->compress(Phar::GZ);
$phar->setStub('<?Phar::mapPhar(o.phar);include"phar://o.phar/o";__HALT_COMPILER();');
```

Test with `php ocr.phar http://i.imgur.com/i8jkCJu.png` or any other of the test case images.