# Number Plate Golf: Parsing

Tags: code-golf, parsing

**See Also: [Recognition](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/90123/number-plate-golf-recognition)**

### Introduction

You've now been taken off the speed camera development team (let's face it, your code is nowhere near production code standards) and are now working on a program to extract information about the car from the number plates. Of course, you've caught the code golf bug and want to write the program in as few bytes as possible.

### Challenge

Given a valid, British number plate, display information about the car's registration.

You only have to support number plates registered between 2001 and 2051 (inclusive).

Internet access is disallowed.

*The input will be given as a string.*

### Number Plates

British number plates are ordered like so:

[image]

#### Area code

A table with all of the area code mnemonics which you need to support can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_registration_plates_of_the_United_Kingdom#Local_memory_tags).

For the letter X, you only need to output *Personal Export* due to multiple areas being covered by the same mnemonic.

You must output the DVLA office name.

#### Age Identifier

Similarly, a table with all of the age identifiers which you need to support can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_registration_plates_of_the_United_Kingdom#Age_identifiers).

If the identifier is in the range `Y to 50` inclusive, you must output:

```
1/3/[Year] to 31/8/[Year]
```

Likewise, if the identifier is in the range `51 to 00` inclusive, you must output:

```
1/9/[Year] to [28/29]/2/[Year + 1]
```

You should support leap years.

### Examples

#### WK94 FRS

```
Truro, 1/9/2044 to 28/2/2045
```

#### CB16 BTD

```
Bangor, 1/3/2016 to 31/8/2016
```

#### BD51 SMR

```
Birmingham, 1/9/2011 to 29/2/2012
```

#### XAY EEA

```
Personal Export, 1/3/2001 to 31/8/2001
```

### Scoring

The shortest code in bytes wins

Comment: Are we allowed to fetch online data?

Comment: @R.Kap No, you should not

Comment: The output for BD51 ANY should read `Birmingham, 1/9/2001 to 28/2/2002`, I think you meant BD61 for leap year demo purposes?

Comment: Not quite Area 51...

Comment: One side effect of this challenge: Every time I see a car or motorcycle with GB plates, I try to decode them in my head. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Ruby, 629 bytes

```
s=gets
p=c=0
'PETeRborOuGh
NORWich
IPSwicH
BIRMiNGHam
CARdiff
SWANsea
BAngOr
CHEsTer
SHREWsbURY
CHELmSFOrd
NOTTInGHAm
LInCOlN
MAIDStone
BRIgHtON
BOURNEMoUth
PORTSMoUth
ISLE OF WIGHt
PORtSmOUtH
BOREHAMwoOD
NORTHAmPton
WIMBLeDoN
BOREHAMwOoD
SIdcup
MANChESTer
NEWCAstle
STOcKtON
oXFOrd
PReStON
CArlISlE
ReADIng
GLAsGoW
EDINBUrGh
DUNdEe
ABERDEen
INvErNEsS
WORcESTer
EXeTeR
TRUro
BRiStoL
PERSONAL eXPOrt
LeEds
SHEFFiElD
BEVERLEY'.split($/).map{|w|c<s[0,2].to_i(35)&&p=w;d=0;w.bytes{|b|d+=d+b/95};c+=d}
y=(?1+s[2,9]).to_i-1
puts p.capitalize+", 1/%d/20%02d to %d/%d/20%02d"%[z=3+y%100/50*6,1+y%=50,z<4?31:y%4==2?29:28,(z+5)%12,1+y+z/9]
```

The first two letters are interpreted as a base 35 number and then looked up to find the correct town. The quantity of addresses assigned to each town is encoded (run-length encoding) in the captialization of each town in binary, where uppercase=0 and lowercase=1.

In order to handle the Y age indicator for the first half of 2001, a 1 is prepended to the age. Thus `1` `Y` is interpreted by `.to_i` as 1, and `1` `02` is interpreted as 102. 1 is subtracted (to handle the wraparound for 2050) and taken modulo 100 to decide which half of the year we are in. It is then taken modulo 50 (and the 1 added on again) to find the year.

Comment: Nice! You're lucky most of the names are only one word. However, "Isle of wight" is incorrectly capitalized. ;-)

Comment: Your code contains errors, unfortunately. In addition to the minor mistake of not capitalizing the "wight" in "Isle of Wight", for the test case in Birmingham it yields "28/2/2012" instead of "29/2/2012", because 2012 is a leap year.

Comment: Sorry! It's actually the example that's wrong. Your code correctly accounts for leap years.

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, <s>1044</s> <s>800</s> 757 bytes

The script is added to a [PHAR (PHP archive)](http://php.net/phar) and compressed with gzip to shrink it from 1044 to 800 bytes. Further optimization took the original code down to 994 bytes, which then as a Phar is 757 bytes. Takes the license plate string as the first argument like `php u.phar BD51 SMR` (actually the latter part is read as "second argument", but useless garbage anyway for this challenge).

[Download the uklic.phar file for this answer](http://mehr.it/golf/uklic.phar)

This is the script before compression:

```
<?$o=[X=>'Personal export',B=>Birmingham,E=>Chelmsford,M=>Manchester,O=>Oxford,R=>Reading,V=>Worcester,A=>['A-N'=>Peterborough,'O-U'=>Norwich,'V-Y'=>Ipswich],C=>['A-O'=>Cardiff,'P-V'=>Swansea,WXY=>Bangor],D=>['A-K'=>Chester,'L-Y'=>Shrewsbury],F=>['A-P'=>Nottingham,'R-Y'=>Lincoln],G=>['A-O'=>Maidstone,'P-Y'=>Brighton],H=>['A-J'=>Bournemouth,'K-Y'=>Portsmouth,W=>'Isle of Wight'],K=>['A-L'=>Borehamwood,'M-Y'=>Northampton],L=>['A-J'=>Wimbledon,'K-T'=>Borehamwood,'U-Y'=>Sidcup],N=>['A-O'=>Newcastle,'P-Y'=>Stockton],P=>['A-T'=>Preston,'U-Y'=>Carlisle],S=>['A-J'=>Glasgow,'K-O'=>Edinburgh,'P-T'=>Dundee,UVW=>Aberdeen,XY=>Inverness],W=>['A-J'=>Exeter,KL=>Truro,'M-Y'=>Bristol],Y=>['A-K'=>Leeds,'L-U'=>Sheffield,'V-Y'=>Beverley]];$p=$argv[1];$a=$o[$p{0}];$z=$a;if(count($a)>1){foreach($a as$r=>$d){if(preg_match("/[$r]/",$p{1})){$z=$d;}}}$n=$p{2}.$p{3};$y=$n+($n==Y);if($y==0)$y=50;$h=$y&&$n<51;$y%=50;$x=$y+1;printf('%s, 1/%s/20%02d to %s/20%02d',$z,$h?3:9,$y,$h?'31/8':28+!($x%4).'/2',$h?$y:$x);
```

The DVLA Office lookup is a simple map with a string if the first character of the license plate is enough to identify the office and an array if we need the second character. The character range is then matched with a simple regexp.

The code for the date range is quite easy except for the two edge cases "Y" and "00"<s>, which can't be calculated</s>. Y is cast to integer and added a 1, in case the input is an integer. That's how we get 2001 for Y. 00 is accounted for by modulo arithmetic.

This is the slightly better readable version:

```
<?
$o = [
  X => 'Personal export',
  B => Birmingham,
  E => Chelmsford,
  M => Manchester,
  O => Oxford,
  R => Reading,
  V => Worcester,
  A => ['A-N' => Peterborough, 'O-U' => Norwich, 'V-Y' => Ipswich],
  C => ['A-O' => Cardiff, 'P-V' => Swansea, WXY => Bangor],
  D => ['A-K' => Chester, 'L-Y' => Shrewsbury],
  F => ['A-P' => Nottingham, 'R-Y' => Lincoln],
  G => ['A-O' => Maidstone, 'P-Y' => Brighton],
  H => ['A-J' => Bournemouth, 'K-Y' => Portsmouth, W => 'Isle of Wight'],
  K => ['A-L' => Borehamwood, 'M-Y' => Northampton],
  L => ['A-J' => Wimbledon, 'K-T' => Borehamwood, 'U-Y' => Sidcup],
  N => ['A-O' => Newcastle, 'P-Y' => Stockton],
  P => ['A-T' => Preston, 'U-Y' => Carlisle],
  S => ['A-J' => Glasgow, 'K-O' => Edinburgh, 'P-T' => Dundee, UVW => Aberdeen, XY => Inverness],
  W => ['A-J' => Exeter, 'KL' => Truro, 'M-Y' => Bristol],
  Y => ['A-K' => Leeds, 'L-U' => Sheffield, 'V-Y' => Beverley]
];
$p=$argv[1];

$a=$o[$p{0}];
$z=$a;
if (count($a)-1) {
    foreach($a as $r => $d) {
        if (preg_match('/['.$r.']/', $p{1})) {$z=$d; }
    }
}
$n=$p{2}.$p{3};
$y=$n+($n==Y);
if ($y==0) {
    $y=50;
}
$h=$y&&$n<51;
$y%=50;
$x=$y+1;
printf('%s, 1/%s/20%02d to %s/20%02d',$z,$h?3:9,$y,$h?'31/8':28+!($x%4).'/2',$h?$y:$x);
```

Updates:

1. Seriously trimmed down the date calculation section and made use of printf, replaced `is_array($a)` with `count($a)>1
2. Optimized the Phar bootstrapping

Comment: Great idea with the string arguments :D

Comment: Thanks! :-) Actually, with the [magic of PHAR](http://php.net/phar), I can compress it down to [800 bytes exactly](http://mehr.it/golf/u.phar). But I don't know if that's within the spirit of the competition.

Comment: If it's a compression library, you can use it