# Perfect License Plates

Tags: code-golf, sequence

## Perfect License Plates

Starting a few years ago, I made myself a little game while driving around: checking if nearby license plates are "perfect". It's relatively rare, but exciting when you find one.

To check if a license plate is perfect:

1. Sum up the characters, with A = 1, B = 2, ...  Z = 26.
2. Take each consecutive chunk of numerals, and sum them; multiply each of these sums together.

If the values in part 1 and part 2 are equal, congratulations! You've found a perfect license plate!

#### Examples

```
License plate: AB3C4F

Digits -> 3 * 4 
        = 12
Chars  -> A + B + C + F 
        = 1 + 2 + 3 + 6 
        = 12
12 == 12 -> perfect!


License plate: G34Z7T

Digits -> (3 + 4) * 7 
        = 49
Chars  -> G + Z + T 
        = 7 + 26 + 20 
        = 53
49 != 53 -> not perfect!


License plate: 10G61

Digits -> (1 + 0) * (6 + 1)
        = 7
Chars  -> G
        = 7
7 == 7 -> perfect!
```

### The Challenge

I used license plates of length 5 and 6 as examples, but this procedure is valid for any plate length. Your challenge is, for a given length N, return the number of perfect license plates of that length. For the purposes of the challenge, a valid license plate is any combination of digits 0-9 and characters A-Z. The plate must contain *both a character and a numeral* to be considered potentially perfect. For checking purposes, here are the values I got (though I can't be 100% about their correctness, hahaha)

```
N < 2: 0
N = 2: 18
N = 3: 355
N = 4: 8012
```

#### Notes

If somehow it makes the problem simpler in your language, you may output the **proportion** of perfect license plates for a given N, to at least 2 significant digits.

```
N < 2: 0
N = 2: 0.0138888...
N = 3: 0.0076088...
N = 4: 0.0047701...
```

OR, you may output the equivalent value **mod 256**

```
N < 2: 0
N = 2: 18
N = 3: 99
N = 4: 76
```

Shortest wins!

Comment: Welcome to the site! I think this is a good challenge, but the additional permitted outputs make it hard to actually score answers. PPCG looks for objective winning criteria, and it's hard to do that when there are so many freedoms; this doesn't only change the output format, this actually changes what you're allowed to output. I would recommend editing out the other options and just making it required to output the number of perfect license plates for `N`.

Comment: I would personally enjoy this challenge a lot more if it was simply validating whether a given licence plate is perfect or not (especially because you don't have definitive numbers for the test cases. It's probably ok though, as long as the potential calculated results are reduced. Not sure about how other people feel though. Nice idea though!

Comment: I agree with Mistah Figgins; I feel like this way it's more about finding a pattern, which is still an interesting challenge, but I think it might attract more answers if it were just a validation check. Nice challenge though!

Comment: I get `N=2:18`, `N=3:355` and `N=4:8012`. Anyone else to verify those numbers?

Comment: @Dada Paper and pen, my friend. Paper and pen.

Comment: @Okx What? I'm not going to check 350 numbers by hand. I'm hoping someone else will implement a solution to this challenge and come up with either my numbers or OP's numbers.

Comment: @Dada Same here, also 28% into the `N=5` case.

Comment: Perhaps @Willbeing should post his implementation. The test cases need to be correct, so it's important to know whether `N=4` is currently wrong or not. At this time, it appears that `8012` is probably the correct answer.

Comment: @Dada I verify those numbers with my solution as well.

Comment: [*I think that*](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/90123/number-plate-golf-recognition) [**we need a**](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/90333/number-plate-golf-parsing) [tag:license-plate] tag ;)

Comment: y'all are absolutely right, my test implementation used something, uh, a little nonsensical for pulling out the numerals. I switched to using regex and got your numbers, lemme change it :) 

Also with regards to changing the challenge for simply checking if a license plate is perfect, I like that idea. I assume since people are already answering, this is more of a "in the future" kind of suggestion?

Comment: @Willbeing I'm pretty sure you can make another challenge, though it might be considered duplicate, but yes, it's more for the future. I still see the other input formats; could you remove those? Nobody has used those yet and it's confusing because you have multiple allowed output formats.

Comment: "The plate must contain both a character and a numeral to be considered potentially perfect." - it would have been more pleasant without this special case

Comment: I have posted a [closely related challenge](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/115850/detect-the-nearly-perfect-licence-plates), hoping that it will draw attention on this wonderful question, as well as simplifying this a bit, only checking for (nearly) perfect licence plate.

Comment: Awr, my state can't have perfect plates. All the letters are grouped up. :(

Comment: I'll extend the bounty if not claimed by the expiration date. I've spent like 3 hours of my own time trying to mathematically do this, and I'm stumped.

Comment: I'm not convinced there is a way to do that doesn't at some point somewhere entail counting or evaluating different factorizations of a number. I would be surprised if there is a constant time method to this. (please someone make a chat room for this challenge)

Comment: @carusocomputing I tried my best but came up empty. I sent it to my math teacher and he is empty so far

Comment: @carusocomputing I may have gone from `Ω(exp(sqrt(n))` to polynomial and be able to compute `f(50)=1841915557862572657366350825010485722223950961479824748648944192448338932` in 36 seconds, but I see no path to linear or even constant time. And giving such an answer here would be problematic anyway, as the original question is code-golf. My answer already got a downvote, probably for not being golfy enough.

Comment: @carusocomputing I think I might be getting somewhere by observing a pattern with n-simplex numbers and partitioning numbers to get section 1, but it seems to not be getting anywhere close to anything better than `O(n^2)` or worse.

Comment: @christiansievers if there's no improvement on other answers, I'll be giving the bounty to you.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino if you edit your answer with this version (as a supplemental answer, not a replacement of your current) and a proof of quadratic time, I'll award the bounty to you instead.

Comment: @carusocomputing Alright, thanks. I'll ping you when (if) I'm done. It looks like it might end up turning out to be `O(n^3)` though... :( I'll finish it and see what it turns out to be.

Comment: I'm working on it too, I think my complexity so far is about O(n^4*log(n)) or lower; I get the result for n=100 in about 1 minute.

Comment: @aditsu That's about the same speed I get. On reasonable hardware (i5-4590S) my latest GAP program that I talked about above computes `f(100)=2428...9962` in 53 seconds, a C++ version of the code needs 31 seconds, saving less than I expected.

Answer (score 9):

## Python 3.6, 150 bytes

```
f=lambda n,t=-1,p=-1,a=0:sum(f(n-1,*((t,c+p*(p>=0),a),((t<0 or t)*(p<0 or p),-1,a-c))[c<0])for c in range(-26,10))if n else 0<(t<0 or t)*(p<0 or p)==a
```

results:

```
f(2) = 18
f(3) = 355
f(4) = 8012
f(5) = 218153
```

Ungolfed version with explanation:

```
digits=[*range(10)]
letters=[*range(1,27)]

def f(n, dt=-1, dp=-1, lt=0):
    if n:
        for d in digits:
            yield from f(n - 1,
                         dt,
                         d if dp < 0 else dp + d,
                         lt
                         )

        for l in letters:
            yield from f(n - 1,
                         dp if dt < 0 else dt if dp < 0 else dt*dp,
                         -1,
                         lt + l
                         )
    else:
        yield 0 < lt == (dt<0 or dt)*(dp<0 or dp)
```

The problem boils down to searching a tree in which each level of the tree corresponds to a position in a license plate number and each node has 36 children (10 digits and 26 letters).  The function does a recursive search of the tree, accumulating the values for the digits and letters as it goes.

```
n is the number of levels to search. 
dp accumulates the sum of a group of digits.
dt accumulates the product of the digit sums.
lt accumulates the sum of the letter values.

For dp and dt, a value < 0 indicates it is not initialized.
```

Golf included, converting the for loops to sums of generators:

```
sum(f(n-1, 
      dt,
      d if dp < 0 else dp + d,
      lt) for d in digits)
+
sum(f(n-1,
      dp if dt<0 else dt if dp<0 else dt*dp,
      -1,
      lt+l) for l in letters)
```

Then combining the generators.  Encode letters, A to Z, as -1 to -26 and digits as 0 to 9.  So the sum becomes:

```
sum(f(n-1, *args) for c in range(-26, 10)),
```

where args is:

```
((dp if dt<0 else dt if dp<0 else dt*dp, -1, lt-l) if c <0 else
 (dt, d if dp<0 else dp+d, lt))
```

The rest of the golfing is converting the function to a lambda, shortening variable names, and simplifying expressions.

Comment: This is an eloquent solution, what would the runtime be? `n*n*log(n)` or something similar?

Comment: @carusocomputing Thanks.  The solution still generates all possible permutations of the given length, so it has the same complexity as the other solutions.  Something like k**n, where k is the number of symbols in the alphabet (e.g., 10 digits + 26 letters = 36) and n is the number of symbols on a license plate.  Running it for n = 5 requires checking 36^5 = 60,466,176 permutations and took a minute or two (memoization might speed it up, but would cost a lot of bytes ;-)  ).

Answer (score 6):

## Dyalog APL, <s>57</s> 56 bytes

```
+/(+/0⌈a-9)=×/c*⍨-2-/0,⌈\(+\a×b)×c←2>/0,⍨b←9≥a←↑1↓,⍳⎕⍴36
```

(assumes `⎕io←0`)

`a` matrix of all valid licence plates (except `00...0`) encoded with: 0-9 for digits, 10-35 for letters

`b` bitmask for where digits occur

`c` bitmask for the last digit in every group of consecutive digits

Comment: [Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/apl-dyalog#U9Z71DfV0/9R2wQDrkcd7Wn/tfU1tPUNHvV0JOpaatoenq6frPWod4Wuka6@gQ5QNEZDOybx8PQkzcPTk4GajOxAwr0rkoBsy0edSxOB9KO2iYaP2iYDhTcDzX7Uu8XY7D/Q6P9pXIZcaVxGQGwMxCYA "APL (Dyalog Unicode) – TIO Nexus") for 1-4 needs more memory for 4, but [there are ways around that too!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#@5@anJGvoPSob6qn/6O2CQYKj7pbFLT1NbT1DR71dCTqWmraHp6un6z1qHeFrpGuvoEOUDRGQzsm8fD0JM3D05OBeozsQMK9K5KAbMtHnUsTgfSjtomGj9omA4U3mzzq3WJspqRQo@DrGBEebGtkauaroJ9fUKKfm1KZmJOfrm9oqmegb2aiX5qXmZyfkqoPEVbQLU4uyiwoUfj/HwA "Bash – TIO Nexus")

Answer (score 4):

## Python 2, <s>359</s> 295 bytes

Rather long; this is the trivial solution. I'm confident this is correct, though it does not match the test cases in the challenge. The solutions I'm getting match Dada's answers.

```
import itertools as i,re as r,string as s
print len([''.join(x)for x in i.product(s.lowercase+s.digits,repeat=input())if(lambda t:r.search('\\D',t)and r.search('\\d',t)and reduce(int.__mul__,[sum(map(int,k))for k in r.split('\\D+',t)if k])==sum([k-96 for k in map(ord,t) if k>96]))(''.join(x))])
```

-64 bytes thanks to suggestions from @numbermaniac

Comment: You can save about three bytes in c(x) and the last line; remove a space between 96 and `for`; between `map(ord,x)` and `if`; and in the last line, between `.join(x)` and `for`. I think you can also save even more if you redefine the functions to lambdas.

Comment: @numbermaniac Thanks! (64 bytes total)

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>291</s> <s>287</s> <s>276</s> 273 bytes

```python
lambda n:sum(1for x in s.product(y+z,repeat=n)if(lambda p,s=set:reduce(int.__mul__,[sum(map(int,i))for i in re.findall(r"\d+",p)],1)==sum(ord(i)-64for i in p if ord(i)>64)and s(p)&s(y)and s(p)&s(z))(''.join(x)))
import re,itertools as s,string as t
y=t.uppercase
z=t.digits
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#TY7BasMwEETv/gqRQ6MlqiGQ5mBQf6QpRo0ks8WWFu0aYv@8a9HS9rYzzLydaG/b6KYP71TqeJ70OeaiHgqT4pZK9vNd9HJaTQkUnNgEGPVPgQxbDtKVsKeCxiRt30/z2PfmraImR9U0CFChWKEltBGTd@Ooy@HmTwdD8G7OYG1t5OI1wvP18psnhVF926/XC7jkFWuCJ9bLf7EC6OOx/cyY9AMAGpwoF9nfGZRQJOeRlWPFhqVgGuotzWKlnYlCuTsOzborjwMKb39zXRqCfoGuUbT3RKGJ@5TtCw)

---

Results:

```python
0 0
1 0
2 18
3 355
4 8012
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 117 bytes

116 bytes of code + `-p` flag.

```perl
$"=",";@F=(A..Z,0..9);map{$r=1;$r*=eval s/./+$&/gr for/\d+/g;$r+=64-ord for/\pl/g;$\+=!$r*/\pl/*/\d/}glob"{@F}"x$_}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/perl5#U1YsSC3KUdAt@K@iZKuko2Tt4Gar4ainF6VjoKdnqWmdm1hQrVJka2itUqRlm1qWmKNQrK@nr62ipp9epJCWX6Qfk6Ktnw6U1bY1M9HNL0qBCBbkgARjtG0VgfrAXCCZol@bnpOfpFTt4FarVKESX1v9/78xAA)

It feels quite suboptimal, but I 'm out of ideas right now.
The code itself is very inefficient as it computes every permutation of `a..z,0..9` of length `n` (it takes roughly 1 second for `n=3`, ~15 seconds for `n=4` and ~7 minutes for `n=5`).
The algorithm is quite straight forward: for every possible plate of size `n` (generated with `glob"{@F}"x$_` - the `glob` operator is quite magic), `$r*=eval s/./+$&/gr for/\d+/g;` computes the product of every chunk of digits, and `$r+=64-ord for/\pl/g` subtract to it the weight of the letters. Then, we increment the counter `$\` if the `$r` is `0` (`!$r`) and if the plate contains numbers and letters (`/\pl/*/\d/`). `$\` is implicitly printed at the end thanks to `-p` flag.

Note that the numbers I obtain are `n=2 -> 18`, `n=3 -> 355`, `n=4 -> 8012`, `n=5 -> 218153`. I'm pretty sure these are the right ones, but I might be mistaken, in which case let me know and I'll deleted this answer.

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 71 bytes

Full program body. Prompts for N. N≥4 requires huge amounts of memory and computation.

```apl
+/((+/⊢⍳∩)∘⎕A=(×/'\d+'⎕S{+/⍎¨⍵.Match}))¨l/⍨∧⌿∨/¨c∘.∊l←,(∊c←⎕D⎕A)∘.,⍣⎕⊂⍬
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/apl-dyalog#e9TRnvZfW19DQ1v/UdeiR72bH3Ws1HzUMeNR31RHW43D0/XVY1K01YG84Gqgit6@Qyse9W7V800sSc6o1dQ8tCIHKLjiUcfyRz37H3Ws0D@0IhmoWe9RR1fOo7YJOhpARjKQAdTvAjIRZLKezqPexUDOo66mR71r/j/qaP@fxmXIlcZlBMTGAA)

Answer (score 3):

### [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org), 416 bytes

Won't win on code size, and far from constant time, but uses math to speed up a lot!

```
x:=X(Integers);
z:=CoefficientsOfUnivariatePolynomial;
s:=Size;

f:=function(n)
 local r,c,p,d,l,u,t;
 t:=0;
 for r in [1..Int((n+1)/2)] do
  for c in [r..n-r+1] do
   l:=z(Sum([1..26],i->x^i)^(n-c));
   for p in Partitions(c,r) do
    d:=x;
    for u in List(p,k->z(Sum([0..9],i->x^i)^k)) do
     d:=Sum([2..s(u)],i->u[i]*Value(d,x^(i-1))mod x^s(l));
    od;
    d:=z(d);
    t:=t+Binomial(n-c+1,r)*NrArrangements(p,r)*
         Sum([2..s(d)],i->d[i]*l[i]);
   od;
  od;
 od;
 return t;
end;
```

To squeeze out the unnecessary whitespace and get one line with 416 bytes, pipe through this:

```
sed -e 's/^ *//' -e 's/in \[/in[/' -e 's/ do/do /' | tr -d \\n
```

My old "designed for Windows XP" laptop can calculate `f(10)` in less than one minute and go much further in under an hour:

```
gap> for i in [2..15] do Print(i,": ",f(i),"\n");od;
2: 18
3: 355
4: 8012
5: 218153
6: 6580075
7: 203255386
8: 6264526999
9: 194290723825
10: 6116413503390
11: 194934846864269
12: 6243848646446924
13: 199935073535438637
14: 6388304296115023687
15: 203727592114009839797
```

### How it works

Suppose that we first only want to know the number of perfect license
plates fitting the pattern `LDDLLDL`, where `L` denotes a letter and
`D` denotes a digit. Assume we have a list `l` of numbers such that
`l[i]` gives the number of ways the letters can give the value `i`,
and a similar list `d` for the values we get from the digits. Then the
number of perfect licence plates with common value `i` is just
`l[i]*d[i]`, and we get the number of all perfect licence plates with
our pattern by summing this over all `i`. Let's denote the operation
of getting this sum by `l@d`.

Now even if the best way to get these lists was to try all
combinations and count, we can do this independently for the letters
and the digits, looking at `26^4+10^3` cases instead of `26^4*10^3`
cases when we just run through all plates fitting the pattern. But we
can do much better: `l` is just the list of coefficients of
`(x+x^2+...+x^26)^k` where `k` is the number of letters, here `4`.

Similarly, we get the numbers of ways to get a sum of digits in a run
of `k` digits as the coefficients of `(1+x+...+x^9)^k`. If there is
more than one run of digits, we need to combine the corresponding
lists with an operation `d1#d2` that at position `i` has as value the
sum of all `d1[i1]*d2[i2]` where `i1*i2=i`. This is the Dirichlet
convolution, which is just the product if we interpret the lists as
coefficients of Dirchlet series. But we have already used them as
polynomials (finite power series), and there is no good way to
interpret the operation for them. I think this mismatch is part of
what makes it hard to find a simple formula. Let's use it on
polynomials anyway and use the same notation `#`. It is easy to
compute when one operand is a monomial: we have `p(x) # x^k = p(x^k)`.
Together with the fact that it is bilinear, this gives a nice (but not
very efficient) way to compute it.

Note that `k` letters give a value of at at most `26k`, while `k`
single digits can give a value of `9^k`. So we will often get unneeded
high powers in the `d` polynomial. To get rid of them, we can compute
modulo `x^(maxlettervalue+1)`. This gives a big speed up and, though I
didn't immediately notice, even helps golfing, because we now know
that the degree of `d` is not bigger then that of `l`, which
simplifies the upper limit in the final `Sum`. We get an even better
speed up by doing a `mod` calculation in the first argument of `Value`
(see comments), and doing the whole `#` computation at a lower level
gives an incredible speed up. But we're still trying to be a
legitimate answer to a golfing problem.

So we have got our `l` and `d` and can use them to compute the number
of perfect licence plates with pattern `LDDLLDL`. That is the same
number as for the pattern `LDLLDDL`. In general, we can change the
order of the runs of digits of different length as we like,
`NrArrangements` gives the number of possibilities. And while there
must be one letter between the runs of digits, the other letters are
not fixed. The `Binomial` counts these possibilities.

Now it remains to run through all possible ways of having lengths of
runs digits. `r` runs through all numbers of runs, `c` through all
total numbers of digits, and `p` through all partitions of `c` with
`r` summands.

The total number of partitions we look at is two less than the number
of partitions of `n+1`, and the partition functions grows like
`exp(sqrt(n))`. So while there are still easy ways to improve the
running time by reusing results (running through the partitions in a
different order), for a fundamental improvement we need to avoid
looking at each partition seperately.

### Computing it fast

Note that `(p+q)@r = p@r + q@r`. On its own, this just helps avoid
some multiplications. But together with `(p+q)#r = p#r + q#r` it means
that we can combine by simple addition polynomials corresponding to
different partitions. We can't just add them all, because we still
need to know with which `l` we have to `@`-combine, which factor we
have to use, and which `#`-extensions are still possible.

Let's combine all polynomials corresponding to partitions with the same
sum and length, and already account for the multiple ways of
distributing the lengths of runs of digits. Different from what I
speculated in the comments, I don't need to care about the smallest
used value or how often it is used, if I make sure that I won't extend
with that value.

Here is my C++ code:

```
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<iostream>
#include<gmpxx.h>

using bignum = mpz_class;
using poly = std::vector<bignum>;

poly mult(const poly &a, const poly &b){
  poly res ( a.size()+b.size()-1 );
  for(int i=0; i<a.size(); ++i)
    for(int j=0; j<b.size(); ++j)
      res[i+j]+=a[i]*b[j];
  return res;
}

poly extend(const poly &d, const poly &e, int ml, poly &a, int l, int m){
  poly res ( 26*ml+1 );
  for(int i=1; i<std::min<int>(1+26*ml,e.size()); ++i)
    for(int j=1; j<std::min<int>(1+26*ml/i,d.size()); ++j)
      res[i*j] += e[i]*d[j];
  for(int i=1; i<res.size(); ++i)
    res[i]=res[i]*l/m;
  if(a.empty())
    a = poly { res };
  else
    for(int i=1; i<a.size(); ++i)
      a[i]+=res[i];
  return res;
}

bignum f(int n){
  std::vector<poly> dp;
  poly digits (10,1);
  poly dd { 1 };
  dp.push_back( dd );
  for(int i=1; i<n; ++i){
    dd=mult(dd,digits);
    int l=1+26*(n-i);
    if(dd.size()>l)
      dd.resize(l);
    dp.push_back(dd);
  }

  std::vector<std::vector<poly>> a;
  a.reserve(n);

  a.push_back( std::vector<poly> { poly { 0, 1 } } );
  for(int i=1; i<n; ++i)
    a.push_back( std::vector<poly> (1+std::min(i,n+i-i)));
  for(int m=n-1; m>0; --m){
    //    std::cout << "m=" << m << "\n";
    for(int sum=n-m; sum>=0; --sum)
      for(int len=0; len<=std::min(sum,n+1-sum); ++len){
        poly d {a[sum][len]} ;
        if(!d.empty())
          for(int sumn=sum+m, lenn=len+1, e=1;
              sumn+lenn-1<=n;
              sumn+=m, ++lenn, ++e)
            d=extend(d,dp[m],n-sumn,a[sumn][lenn],lenn,e);
      }
  }
  poly let (27,1);
  let[0]=0;
  poly lp { 1 };
  bignum t { 0 };
  for(int sum=n-1; sum>0; --sum){
    lp=mult(lp,let);
    for(int len=1; len<=std::min(sum,n+1-sum); ++len){
      poly &a0 = a[sum][len];
      bignum s {0};
      for(int i=1; i<std::min(a0.size(),lp.size()); ++i)
        s+=a0[i]*lp[i];
      bignum bin;
      mpz_bin_uiui( bin.get_mpz_t(), n-sum+1, len );
      t+=bin*s;
    }
  }
  return t;
}

int main(){
  int n;
  std::cin >> n;
  std::cout << f(n) << "\n" ;
}
```

This uses the GNU MP library. On debian, install `libgmp-dev`. Compile
with `g++ -std=c++11 -O3 -o pl pl.cpp -lgmp -lgmpxx`. The program
takes its argument from stdin. For timing, use `echo 100 | time ./pl`.

At the end `a[sum][length][i]` gives the number of ways in which `sum`
digits in `length` runs can give the number `i`. During computation,
at the beginning of the `m` loop, it gives the number of ways that can
be done with numbers greater than `m`. It all starts with
`a[0][0][1]=1`.
Note that this is a superset of the numbers we need to compute the
function for smaller values. So at almost the same time, we could
compute all values up to `n`.

There is no recursion, so we have a fixed number of nested loops. (The
deepest nesting level is 6.) Each loop goes through a number of values
that is linear in `n` in the worst case. So we need only polynomial
time. If we look closer at the nested `i` and `j` loops in `extend`,
we find an upper limit for `j` of the form `N/i`. That should only
give a logarithmic factor for the `j` loop. The innermost loop in `f`
(with `sumn` etc) is similar. Also keep in mind that we compute with
numbers that grow fast.

Note also that we store `O(n^3)` of these numbers.

Experimentally, I get these results on reasonable hardware (i5-4590S):
`f(50)` needs one second and 23 MB, `f(100)` needs 21 seconds and 166
MB, `f(200)` needs 10 minutes and 1.5 GB, and `f(300)` needs one hour
and 5.6 GB. This suggests a time complexity better than `O(n^5)`.

Comment: As this is a code golf challenge, this answer _needs_ to be golfed. Sorry.

Comment: @Riker While I don't think my code was overly verbose to start with, I golfed some more and took the burden of determining its size when whitespace is squeezed out.

Comment: What's the runtime of this? I'm trying to calculate it but am less than familiar with the language. Seems like you did do a lot of optimization that I'm not seeing in other answers though, but it also still seems quadratic or perhaps even cubic?

Comment: @carusocomputing I'm afraid it's much worse. I'm handling separately each case of distributing digits among runs of digits, like there is one run of three digits, or there is one run of two digits and one single digit, or there are three single digits, but for `n=5`, there is no case with a run of two digits and two single digits, because then we don't have enough letters to separate the numbers. This is what the three outer `for` loops do: run through all _useful_ partitions of numbers `<n`. (And I just realized I also allow `n` digits. By sheer luck another optimization counts this as 0).

Comment: @carusocomputing Note that for numbers `<n/2`, *all* partitions are useful. And the remaining computations still take their non-constant time. To see what is going on, you could add `Print(p,"\n");` at the beginning of the body of the `for p...` loop. - I got an idea for using one loop less, but it will only help code size.

Comment: @ChristianSievers I still think this is the fastest algorithm so far.

Comment: Saving one loop worked, but didn't reduce code size. - I could avoid a lot of recomputations by visiting the partitions in a different order, 3+2+1 and 3+2+2 directly after 3+2. Even better, I think I can combine some partitions, so that instead of handling 3+3+1+1 and 4+2+1+1 separately, I can extend the combined 3+3+1 and 4+2+1  cases. Combinable partitions need to have the same length, sum, lowest summand and number of appearances of that summand. This might give a polynomial time algorithm. Also, the inner loop computation of `d` should be faster if done less high level. But code-golf!

Comment: I get an amazing speed up by moving the `mod` (which already helped a lot) into `Value`, changing it to `Value(d mod x^(1+QuoInt(s(l)-1,i-1)),x^(i-1))`. That alone allows to compute `f(15)` in 80 seconds.

Comment: Hopefully the +500 will make up for the downvotes due to the length, can tell you put a ton of work into this and it was an interesting follow. I think this can't be solved using pure combinatorics though...

Comment: @carusocomputing Oh thanks, I didn't expect your decision so soon. aditsu's results also seemed very promising. It was only one downvote, but while it couldn't stop my interest in the problem, it made me unsure if I should keep my answer at all and so discouraged me from giving more explanations when I had time. I think I should add some of my new code. Are you more interested in the GAP code that computes `f(100)` in 53 seconds on reasonable hardware, or the same algorithm in C++ (now down to 23 seconds)?

Comment: Don't worry, my code is much longer, and not close to your 23 sec result (although I wrote it in java and haven't tried translating it). I was reluctant to post it due to the golfing expectation. I'd like to see your C++ code as well as an assessment of the complexity.

Comment: @aditsu I added some explanation, the C++ code and some vague ideas about its complexity. Is your approach similar?

Answer (score 2):

## Scala, 265 bytes

```
(n:Int)=>{val i=('A'to'Z')++('0'to'9');Seq.fill(n)(i).flatten.combinations(n).flatMap(_.permutations).map(_.mkString).count(l=>"(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\\d)".r.findAllIn(l).size>0&&l.map(_-64).filter(_>0).sum==l.split("[A-Z]").filter(""<).map(_.map(_-48).sum).reduce(_*_))}
```

**Explanations :**

```
(n:Int) => {
    val i = ('A' to 'Z') ++ ('0' to '9');                       // All license plates available characters.
    Seq.fill(n)(i).flatten                                      // Simulate combination with repetition (each character is present n times)
        .combinations(n)                                        // and generate all combinations of size n (all license plates).
        .flatMap(_.permutations)                                // For each combination, generate all permutations (ex. : Seq('A', '1') => Seq('A', '1') and Seq('1', 'A')), and
        .map(_.mkString)                                        // convert each permutation to String (Seq('A', '1') => "A1").
        .count ( l =>                                           // Then count all strings having :
            "(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\\d)".r.findAllIn(l).size > 0 &&   // at least 1 character and 1 digit and
            l.map(_ - 64).filter(_ > 0).sum ==                  // a sum of characters (> 'A' or > 64) equals to
            l.split("[A-Z]").filter(""<)
                .map(_.map(_ - 48).sum)
                .reduce(_*_)                                    // the product of sum of digits groups (split String by letters to get digits groups)
        )
}
```

*Notes :*

- `-64` and `-48` are used to transform a `Char` (respectively letter and digit) to its `Int` value (`'A' - 64 = 1`, `'B' - 64 = 2`, ..., `'9' - 48 = 9`)
- The filter in `l.split("[A-Z]").filter(""<)` is used to eliminate `""` values if `l` starts with a letter (example : `"A1".split("[A-Z]") => Array("", 1)`). There might be a better and shorter solution

**Test cases :**

```
val f = (n:Int) => ...  // assign function
(1 to 5).foreach ( i =>
    println(s"N = $i: ${f(i)}")
)
```

**Results :**

```
N = 1: 0
N = 2: 18
N = 3: 355
N = 4: 8012
N = 5: 218153
```

The function is pretty slow for `n > 4` since all combinations must be generated.

Answer (score 2):

## Java, <s>382</s> 365 bytes

- Saved 17 bytes, thanks to **Kevin Cruijssen**

**Golfed**

```java
int h(String s){int m=0;for(int c:s.toCharArray())m+=c-48;return m;}
int g(String t){int d=1,c=0;for(String s:t.split("[^0-9]"))d*=h(s);for(String s:t.split("[^A-Z]"))c+=s.charAt(0)-65;return d==c?1:0;}
int f(String t,int n){int m=0;if(t.length()==n)return g(t);for(int d=48;d<58;)m+=f(t+d++,n);for(int c=65;c<91;)m+=f(t+c++,n);return m;}
int s(int n){return f("",n);}
```

**Detailed**

```java
// return sum of adjecent digits
int h(String s)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for(char c : s.toCharArray()) sum += c-'0';
    return sum;
}

// check if perfect
int g(String t)
{
    int d = 1;
    int c = 0;

    for(String s : t.split("[^0-9]")) d *= h(s);
    for(String s : t.split("[^A-Z]")) c += s.charAt(0)-'A';

    return d == c ? 1 : 0;
}

// tree of enumerations
int f(String t, int n)
{
    // base case
    if(t.length() == n)
    {
        return g(t);
    }

    // enumeration
    int sum = 0;
    for(char d='0'; d<='9'; d++) sum += f(t+d, n);
    for(char c='A'; c<='Z'; c++) sum += f(t+c, n);

    return sum;
}

int s(int n){ return f("",n); }
```

Comment: I think you need a function that only takes `n` as input.

Comment: @ChristianSievers fixed

Comment: Some things to golf for your current code: `int h(String s){int m=0;for(int c:s.toCharArray())m+=c-48;return m;}int g(String t){int d=1,c=0;for(String s:t.split("[^0-9]"))d*=h(s);for(String s:t.split("[^A-Z]"))c+=s.charAt(0)-65;return d==c?1:0;}int f(String t,int n){int m=0;if(t.length()==n)return g(t);for(int d=48;d<58;)m+=f(t+d++,n);for(int c=65;c<91;)m+=f(t+c++,n);return m;}int s(int n){return f("",n);}` (**365 bytes**) You can compare your current version with this one to see the changes I did (too much to fit in the remainder of this comment). :)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen thx, 17 bytes off now

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, 55 bytes

```
FNQI<xrG1N0=+ZsN).?=+YZ=Z0;qu*G?HH1Y1sm?<xrG1d00hxrG1dQ
```