# Detect the Nearly Perfect Licence Plates

Tags: code-golf, math, arithmetic, alphabet

***Note:** This is inspired by [this question by **@Willbeing**](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/115007/perfect-license-plates) where task was to count the number of perfect plates of a certain length, but it's slightly different.*

---

We call ***a perfect licence plate*** that plate whose text satisfies the following conditions:

- It consists of characters, which can either be uppercase letters(`[A-Z]`) or digits(`[0-9]`)
- Summing the positions of its letters in the English alphabet, ***1-indexed*** (i.e: `A=1,B=2,...,Z=26`) gives an integer **n**
- Getting each chunk of digits, summing them and then multiplying all the results gives the same result, **n**
- **n** is a perfect square (e.g: `49` *(7<sup>2</sup>)*, `16` *(4<sup>2</sup>)*)

A **nearly perfect licence plate** meets the conditions for a perfect licence plate, except that **n** is *not* a perfect square.

---

## Input

A string representing the text of the licence plate, taken as input in any standard form, except for hardcoding.

## Output

If the given string represents a ***nearly perfect*** licence plate, return a truthy value (e.g: `True` / `1`), otherwise return a falsy value (e.g: `False` / `0`). Any standard form of output is accepted while taking note that [this loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are strictly forbidden.

---

#### Examples

```
licence plate -> output


A1B2C3 -> 1

A + B + C = 1 + 2 + 3 = 6
1 * 2 * 3 = 6 
6 is not a perfect square, 6 = 6 => nearly perfect plate

01G61 -> 1

(0 + 1) * (6 + 1) = 7
G = 7
7 is not a perfect square, 7 = 7 => nearly perfect plate

11BB2 -> 0

(1 + 1) * 2 = 4
B + B = 2 + 2 = 4
4 = 4, but 4 is the square of 2 => perfect license plate (not what we want)

67FF1 -> 0

(6 + 7) * 1 = 13
F + F = 6 + 6 = 12
12 != 13 => not perfect at all!
```

---

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes wins!

Comment: [tag:popularity-contest]

Comment: I think this would be better as [tag:code-golf].

Comment: Let me make sure I understand this. We only output _truthy_ if the licence plate is perfect and `n` is _not_ a perfect square?

Comment: @mathjunkie Yes. **TL;DR:** only if the licence is ***nearly*** perfect (P.S sorry for the late response)

Comment: Before anyone does `s/licence/license/ig` on this, be aware that "licence" is the correct spelling in British English (as well as English in other parts of the world).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>29 28</s> 30 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

+1 byte to fix a bug spotted by ChristianSievers (incorrectly dealing with substrings of only zeros)
+1 byte to fix false positives for `"0"`, `"00"`, ... found during above fixing (0 is a perfect square).

```
i@€ØAS;Æ²$
e€ØAœpV€€LÐfS€P;0⁼Ç
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@5/p8KhpzeEZjsHWh9sObVLhSoVwj04uCAOygMjn8IS0YCAdYG3wqHHP4fb///8rGRo6ORkpAQA)**, or [run tests](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@5/p8KhpzeEZjsHWh9sObVLhSoVwj04uCAOygMjn8IS0YCAdYG3wqHHP4fb/h9uBvP//o5UcDZ2MnI2VdJQMDN3NDIG0oaGTkxGQNjN3c4PwHR0NQPIgQikWAA)

#### How?

```
i@€ØAS;Æ²$ - Link 1: [letter-sum, letter-sum is perfect square?]: plate
i@€        - index of €ach char in plate [reversed @rguments] (1-based, 0 otherwise) in:
   ØA      -     uppercase alphabet
     S     - sum
         $ - last two links as a monad:
      ;    -     concatenate with:
       Æ²  -         is square?

e€ØAœpV€€LÐfS€P;0⁼Ç - Main link: plate                        e.g. "11BB2"
    œp              - partition plate at truthy values of:
e€                  -     is in? for €ach char in plate:
  ØA                -         uppercase alphabet                   [['1','1'],[''],['2']]
      V€€           - evaluate for €ach for €ach                   [[1,1],[],[2]]
          Ðf        - filter keep:
         L          -     length                                   [[1,1],[2]]
            S€      - sum each                                     [2,2]
              P     - product                                      4
               ;0   - concatenate a zero                           [4,0]
                  Ç - last link (1) as a monad (taking plate)      [4,1]
                 ⁼  - equal? (non-vectorising)                     0
```

Comment: Wow, genius Jelly solution!

Comment: What about `11AA0`?

Comment: @ChristianSievers, good catch. Fixed along with another, kind of related, bug and extended the test suite.

Answer (score 7):

## MATL, <s>36</s> <s>34</s> <s>33</s> 35 bytes

```
3Y432YXU"@V!Usvp]GlY2&msy=wtQ:qUm~v
```

Try it at [**MATL Online**](https://matl.io/?code=3Y432YXU%22%40V%21Usvp%5DGlY2%26msy%3DwtQ%3AqUm%7Ev&inputs=%27A1B2C3%27&version=19.9.0)

**Explanation**

```
        % Implicitly grab input as a string
3Y4     % Push the predefined literal '[A-Za-z]+' to the stack
32      % Push the literal 32 to the stack (ASCII for ' ')
YX      % Replace the matched regex with spaces (puts a space in place of all letters)
U       % Convert the string to a number. The spaces make it such that each group of
        % of consecutive digits is made into a number
"       % For each of these numbers
  @V!U  % Break it into digits
  s     % Sum the digits
  v     % Vertically concatenate the entire stack
  p     % Compute the product of this vector
]       % End of for loop
G       % Explicitly grab the input again
lY2     % Push the predefined literal 'ABCD....XYZ' to the stack
&m      % Check membership of each character in the input in this array and 
        % return an array that is 0 where it wasn't a letter and the index in 'ABC..XYZ'
        % when it was a letter
s       % Sum the resulting vector
y       % Duplicate the product of the sums of digits result
=       % Compare to the sum of letter indices result
w       % Flip the top two stack elements
Q       % Add one to this value (N)
t:      % Duplicate and compute the array [1...N]
q       % Subtract 1 from this array to yield [0...N-1]
U       % Square all elements to create all perfect squares between 1 and N^2
m~      % Check to ensure that N is not in the array of perfect squares
v       % Vertically concatenate the stack.
        % Implicitly display the truthy/falsey result
```

Comment: Yields false positives for plates consisting of only zeros, e.g. `'0'` or `'00'` (FWIW I just fixed that in my code too).

Comment: @JonathanAllan Updated.

Answer (score 6):

## Python 2, <s>120</s> 118 bytes

```py
s=t=p=0;r=1
for n in input():
 h=int(n,36)
 if h>9:s+=h-9;r*=t**p
 p=h<10;t=(t+h)*p
print(s==r*t**p)&(int(s**.5)**2<s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#PY5NCoMwEIX3OcWA0CRjLRmlFo0j1IK9icSNDUl6fqu2FN7mez/wMnmnoXxUEooeSGTS0LOmPxENQ3mQ2ai@jeM3M2vkxJ6NDUxiegVYYN7l30npVoDjeUlqOVe1FjBP4PqmjTm7orEBOSF6AZ5dR8YmVil3enN82EeROeDe0Cd1MOLlqhHLLup1/Z34AA)

Interprets each character as a number in base-36 (`h`). Converts to decimal and adds to the sum if `h>9` (meaning it's a letter), otherwise adds to a variable which gets multiplied to form the running product later.

Answer (score 4):

## Python 2, <s>267</s> 207 bytes

<sup>Saved 60 bytes thanks to ovs</sup>

```
import re
def g(l):a=reduce(lambda a,b:a*b,[sum(map(int,list(i)))for i in re.sub(r'\D',' ',l).split()],1);return a==sum(sum(k)for k in[[ord(i)-64for i in x]for x in re.sub(r'\d',' ',l).split()])and a**.5%1>0
```

Function with usage: `print(g('A1B2C3'))`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#Zc/LCsIwEAXQvV@RjSRTYrG@FpUKPv6iupiaVELTNkxS6N/X1IUgLi7M5h7mTqZ1PQVGeqF0zV7CQo4FaTU8tbDYVgoZyirHpJKlH1rRohOmC9IaH4QBgLonZpjpIpH6oRLE7zcuOePSQuqdNUHAQ2ZwJB0G6hgWxezMaT7lJpbLsicVudVh9/XGx3yOv7T6owE7xTBJ0v0yO60nR/G7uIOfs8vmuuUwvQE)

Comment: [Some minor improvements](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#Zc/LCsIwEAXQvV@RjSRTYrG@FpUKPv6iupiaVELTNkxS6N/X1IUgLi7M5h7mTqZ1PQVGeqF0zV7CQo4FaTU8tbDYVgoZyirHpJKlH1rRohOmC9IaH4QBgLonZpjpIpH6oRLE7zcuOePSQuqdNUHAQ2ZwJB0G6hgWxezMaT7lJpbLsicVudVh9/XGx3yOv7T6owE7xTBJ0v0yO60nR/G7uIOfs8vmuuUwvQE)

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>163 156 155 164</s> 161 bytes

```python
from math import*
m=1;s=t=p=0
for x in input():
 try:t+=int(x);p=1
 except:m*=[1,t][p];p=t=0;s+=ord(x.upper())-64
if p:m*=t
print(m==s and sqrt(m)!=int(sqrt(m)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYxBCoMwEEX3OcV0l2hbDC1dKHMScSFVMYsk08kI8fSplsLfvM/j0S5rDI9SFo4e/CgrOE@RpVIebZdQkLBRS2TI4MIx2kSbVoHw3kqNLojOpiO0Cub8nklaX2FvrzL0NBy/YNOlGiNPOt83opm1MbfXU7kF6HRFEZ8Vj5hgDBOkDx9kLr/2H4wpxdpxbOwX)

- saved 7 bytes thanks to  [Jonathan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53748/jonathan-allan) and [Shooqie](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/51530/shooqie)
- saved 1 byte: Also Fixed the false positive issue. Thanks to  [Jonathan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53748/jonathan-allan) for pointing it out!
- added 11 bytes: Previous edit was wrong(the multiplication of sum of digit was going on in an unwanted loop)

Comment: `from math import*` is shorter

Comment: You don't need `a`, just use `for x in input():`. You can have false positives for plates ending with a string of zeros (e.g. `11AA00`), since the  final `m*=t` is not executed.

Comment: Apparently, my code shows false positive for any string with isolated zeros in it ( 3A0B is also shown true )... Thanks for pointing that out @JonathanAllan. I will try to fix it.

Comment: Check the newer version... I have added a new flag variable 'p' to decide whether or not to multiply the sum of digits.

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 80 bytes

79 bytes of code + `-p` flag.

```perl
$.*=eval s/./+$&/gr for/\d+/g;$t-=64-ord for/\pl/g;$_=$.==$t&&($.**.5|0)**2!=$.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/perl5#U1YsSC3KUdAt@K@ip2WbWpaYo1Csr6evraKmn16kkJZfpB@Toq2fbq1SomtrZqKbX5QCESzIAQnG26ro2dqqlKipaQC1a@mZ1hhoamkZKQKF//83MHQ3M1QAAA)

`$.*=eval s/./+$&/gr for/\d+/g;` multiplies the sums of consecutive digits. (I'm using `$.` because it's initial value is `1`, which mean it's the neutral element for multiplication). More precisely, for each chunk of digits (`for/\d+/g`), `s/./+$&/gr` places a `+` before each digit, then the string is `eval`uated, and multiplied with the current product.
Secondly, `$t-=64-ord for/\pl/g;` sums in `$t` each letter (`for/\pl/g`). (`ord` return the ascii code for the letter, and `64-..` makes it be between 1 and 26.
Finally, `$.==$t` checks that both values are the same, and `($.**.5|0)**2!=$.` that it's nor a perfect square.

Answer (score 3):

## Retina, 143 bytes

Returns 1 for true, 0 for false

```
[1-9]
$*
10|01
1
S_`(\D)
O`
{`1(?=1*\n(1+))
$1
)2=`1+\n

[J-S]
1$+
[T-Z]
2$+
T`0L`ddd
1>`\d+\n?
$*
^((?(1)((?(2)\2(11)|111))|1))*\n

^(1*)\n\1$
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#FY4xCoNAFET7OccG/leEnQ0YUhhZExRCIIVWcTVbWHuBeHezNo9XDI85SRf3kcV1gslAu1mC6L9RwkPxjvhFSl0xC6swV4Uh1FWReViB8Vn0E2hyjEPxmeCSDdG@4rIs4C2GJc3qozyL1EI96DQ4IXVjQqJqdrRmYaZhDTT7TnpvYb0nUV7aNn1i0zh4Nu5@hmVXEtY1fw)

**Explanation:**

```
[1-9]
$*
10|01
1
```

First, we replace all non-zero digits with their unary representation. We remove any zeroes with an adjacent digit so that they don't affect our unary operations

```
S_`(\D)
```

Split the resulting string on letters, being careful to exclude empty lines (this is a problem when two letters are consecutive `AA`).

```
O`
{`1(?=1*\n(1+))
$1
)2=`1+\n
```

Sort the string lexicographically. Then repeatedly do the following:

1) Replace each `1` with the number of `1`s on the following line (this mimics multiplication)

2) Remove the second line of `1`s

```
[J-S]
1$+
[T-Z]
2$+
T`0L`ddd
```

Replace letters `J-S` with `1J`, `1K`, etc. and replace letters `T-Z` with `2T`, `2U`, etc. Then, replace each of the groups `A-I`, `J-S`, and `T-Z` with `1-9`. We will be left with the numerical value of each letter (eg. `13` for `M`).

```
1>`\d+\n?
$*
```

Convert every line but the first into unary (the first line is already in unary). Concatenate these lines. We are now left with a string of the form `<product of digits>\n<sum of letters>`.

```
^((?(1)((?(2)\2(11)|111))|1))*\n
```

Replace a square number with the empty string. This uses the ["difference tree" method](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/19413/65425).

```
^(1*)\n\1$
```

Return `1` if the two strings on either side of the `\n` match. Otherwise, return `0`.

Comment: False positives for `11AA0`, `0AA11`, etc.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Thanks! It cost me 11 bytes to fix

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 87 bytes

```ruby
->s{m=0
n=1
s.scan(/(\d+)|./){$1?n*=$1.bytes.sum{_1-48}:m+=$&.ord-64}
m==n&&m**0.5%1>0}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsEiN9ulpSVpuhY3w3XtiqtzbQ248mwNuYr1ipMT8zT0NWJStDVr9PQ1q1UM7fO0bFUM9ZIqS1KB0qW51fGGuiYWtVa52rYqanr5RSm6Zia1XLm2tnlqarlaWgZ6pqqGdga1UONNChTcopUcDZ2MnI2VYrnAPANDdzNDGMfQ0MnJCMYxM3dzA8pA9C5YAKEB)