# Hidden sentences in the license plates

Tags: code-golf, string, random

#### Introduction:

*Inspired by both [Perfect License Plates](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/115007/perfect-license-plates) and [How many points does my license plate give?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/141646/how-many-points-does-my-license-plate-give)*

Just like in the challenges above, me and my little brother had a game of our own with license plates as kids. We tried to create (random/funny) sentences with the (numbers and) letters of the license plates.

For example, I can still remember the license plate of our old car from over ten years ago, because of the silly sentence we had created with it:

```
71-NN-BT
71 Nare Nonnen Bijten Tijgers   [Dutch for: 71 Nasty Nuns Biting Tigers]
```

#### Input:

- A license plate, which for the sake of this challenge will always start with two digits `[0-9]`, followed by four uppercase letters `[A-Z]`.
- Three fixed lists (see below): consisting of Dutch plural nouns; Dutch adjectives; and Dutch verbs.

#### Output:

Using the list of Dutch plural nouns, adjectives and verbs below as input, create a [random](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1325/52210) Dutch sentence with the given license plate using the following rules:

- Start with the numbers, followed by a space;
- And the four letters should either be used in the pattern `adjective noun verb noun` or `noun verb adjective noun` (50/50 [random](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1325/52210)).
  This would mean that the sentence mentioned earlier ("*Nare Nonnen Bijten Tijgers*" / "*Nasty Nuns Biting Tigers*") is in the pattern `adjective noun verb noun`, and this alternative sentence "*Nonnen Negeren Blote Theekopjes*" / "*Nuns Ignoring Naked Teacups*" is in the pattern `noun verb adjective noun`).

#### Lists of words

[Formatted pastebin thanks to *@Arnauld*.](https://pastebin.com/6AEudwZj)

**Nouns:**

```
Aanbeelden [Anvils]
Aardbeien [Strawberries]
Apen [Monkeys]
Appels [Apples]
Auto's [Cars]
Bananen [Bananas]
Bessen [Berries]
Bloemen [Flowers]
Bomen [Trees]
Bijen [Bees]
Cadeaus [Presents]
Cavia's [Guinea pigs]
Cheerleaders [Cheerleaders]
Circusdieren [Circus animals]
Citroenen [Limons]
Dinosaurussen [Dinosaurs]
Dieren [Animals]
Documenten [Documents]
Doctoren [Doctors]
Dolfijnen [Dolphins]
E-mails [Emails]
Edelstenen [Gemstones]
Eekhoorns [Squirles]
Enqûetes [Enquetes]
Ezels [Donkeys]
Fabrieken [Factories]
Fietsen [Bicycles]
Flessen [Bottles]
Fontijnen [Fountains]
Foto's [Photographs]
Giraffen [Girafs]
Glazen [Glasses]
Gummen [Erasers]
Guppy's [Guppies]
Gymschoenen [Gym shoes]
Haaien [Sharks]
Homo's [Gay men]
Honden [Dogs]
Hoofden [Heads]
Horloges [Watches]
Idioten [Idiots]
Idolen [Idols]
IJsklontjes [Ice cubes]
Illusies [Illusions]
Imperia [Empires]
Jassen [Jackets]
Jokers [Jokers]
Jongleurs [Jugglers]
Jurken [Dresses]
Juwelen [Jewels]
Kabels [Cables]
Katten [Cats]
Kauwgomballen [Gum-balls]
Knoppen [Buttons]
Konijnen [Rabbits]
Leesboeken [Reading books]
Leeuwen [Lions]
Legercommandanten [Commander-in-chieves]
Lesbies [Lesbians]
Lummels [Oafs]
Maagden [Virgins]
Mannen [Men]
Mensen [People]
Mieren [Ants]
Muren [Walls]
Neuzen [Noses]
Nieuwkomers [Novices]
Nonnen [Nuns]
Noten [Nuts]
Nummerborden [License plates]
Oceanen [Oceans]
Ogen [Eyes]
Olifanten [Elephants]
Oren [Ears]
Orkanen [Huricanes]
PC's [PCs]
Pizza's [Pizzas]
Politieagenten [Police officers]
Postbezorgers [Mail men]
Potloden [Pencils]
Quads [ATVs]
Quaggamosselen [Quagga mussels]
Querulanten [Querulants]
Quiëtisten [Quietists]
Quizzen [Quizzes]
Radio's [Radios]
Ramen [Windows]
Regiseuren [Film directors]
Rekenmachines [Calculators]
Relschoppers [Hooligans]
Schepen [Ships]
Slakken [Snails]
Slangen [Snakes]
Stegosaurussen [Stegosauruses]
Stoelen [Chairs]
T-rexen [T-rexes]
Tafels [Tables]
Theekopjes [Teacups]
Tijgers [Tigers]
Tovenaars [Wizards]
Uien [Unions]
Uilen [Owls]
Universa [Universes]
Universiteiten [Universities]
USB-sticks [USB-sticks]
Vliegtuigen [Planes]
Vrachtwagens [Trucks]
Vrienden [Friends]
Vrouwen [Women]
Vulkanen [Vulcanos]
Walvissen [Whales]
Wespen [Wasps]
Wormen [Worms]
Worstelaars [Wrestlers]
Wortels [Carrots]
X-assen [X-axes]
X-chromosomen [X-chromosomes]
Xenonlampen [Xenon lamps]
Xylofonen [Xylophones]
Xylofonisten [Xylophonists]
Y-assen [Y-axes]
Y-chromosomen [Y-chromosomes]
Yoghurtdranken [Yugurt drinks]
Yogaleraren [Yoga teachers]
Yogaleraressen [Female yoga teachers]
Zeeën [Seas]
Zeehonden [Seals]
Zeepbellen [Soap bubbles]
Zwanen [Swans]
ZZP'ers [Freelancers]
```

**Verbs:**
*X has some duplicated verbs, because there aren't enough verbs starting with an X in Dutch..*

```
Accepteren [Accepting]
Activeren [Activating]
Amputeren [Amputating]
Amuseren [Amuzing]
Assisteren [Assisting]
Bakken [Baking]
Bedreigen [Threatening]
Bellen [Calling]
Bevruchten [Fertilizing/Impregnating]
Bijten [Biting]
Castreren [Castrating]
Categoriseren [Categorizing]
Centrifugeren [Centrifuging]
Claimen [Claiming]
Coachen [Coaching]
Dagvaardigen [Prosecuting]
Daten [Dating]
Degraderen [Downgrading]
Dienen [Serving]
Dwarsbomen [Thwarting]
Electroniseren [Eletronizing]
Eren [Show respect for]
Erven [Inherit]
Eten [Eating]
Exploderen [Blow up]
Factureren [Invoicing]
Fokken [Breeding]
Föhnen [Blow-drying]
Fotographeren [Photographing]
Frituren [Frying]
Gooien [Throwing]
Graderen [Grading]
Grijpen [Grabbing]
Groeperen [Making groups of]
Groeten [Greeting]
Hacken [Hacking]
Hallucineren [Hallucinating]
Haten [Hating]
Helpen [Helping]
Huren [Renting]
Importeren [Importing]
Inspireren [Inspiring]
Ironiseren [Ridiculing]
Irriteren [Irritating/Annoying]
Isoleren [Isolating]
Jagen op [Hunting on]
Jatten [Stealing]
Jennen [Teasing]
Jongleren met [Juggling with]
Justeren [Adjusting]
Klonen [Cloning]
Koken [Cooking]
Kopen [Buying]
Kraken [Cracking]
Kussen [Kissing]
Labelen [Labeling]
Leasen [Leasing]
Lonken [Ogling]
Loven [Praising]
Lusten [Having a taste for]
Maken [Creating]
Martelen [Torturing]
Merken [Labeling]
Meten [Measuring]
Mollen [Breaking]
Negeren [Ignoring]
Neuken [Having sex with]
Neutraliseren [Neutralizing]
Normaliseren [Normalizing]
Notificeren [Notifying]
Observeren [Observing]
Oliën [Oiling]
Ontbloten [Denuding]
Ontsmetten [Disinfecting]
Ordenen [Sorting]
Penetreren [Penetrating]
Pesten [Bullying]
Plagen [Teasing]
Porren [Poking]
Produceren [Producing]
Quadrilleren met [Quadrille-dancing with]
Quadrupleren [Quadrupling]
Queruleren over [Grumbling about]
Quoteren [Giving a rating to]
Quotiseren [Distributing]
Raadplegen [Consulting]
Redden [Saving]
Reinigen [Cleaning]
Ruilen [Trading]
Roken [Smoking]
Schieten [Shooting]
Schoppen [Kicking]
Schudden [Shaking/Shuffling]
Slaan [Hitting]
Stoppen [Stopping]
Tackelen [Assaulting]
Telen [Cultivating]
Tellen [Counting]
Temperen [Tempering]
Torpederen [Torpedo-ing]
Unificeren [Uniformising]
Unlocken [Unlocking]
Upgraden [Updrading]
Urineren [Urinating]
Utiliseren [Making use of]
Verbinden [Binding]
Verjagen [Scaring away]
Verkopen [Selling]
Vermoorden [Killing]
Verwijderen [Deleting]
Wassen [Washing]
Wekken [Awakening]
Wijzigen [Modifying]
Wreken [Avenging]
Wurgen [Strangling]
Xeroxen [Photocopying]
Xoipen [Sending over the internet]
Xeroxen [Photocopying]
Xoipen [Sending over the internet]
X-en [X-ing]
Yammeren [Yammering]
Yellen [Cheerleading]
Yielding [Calculating percentages of]
YouTube-streamen [YouTube-streaming]
Youtuben [YouTubing]
Zegenen [Blessing]
Zieken [Nagging]
Zien [Seeing]
Zoeken [Searching]
Zoenen [Making out with]
```

**Adjectives:**

```
Abstracte [Abstract]
Achterlijke [Morron]
Afrikaanse [African]
Amerikaanse [American]
Angstaanjagende [Scary]
Baby [Baby]
Blauwe [Blue]
Blote [Naked]
Boze [Angry]
Broze [Fragile]
Charmante [Charming]
Chinese [Chinese]
Chocolade [Chocolade]
Coole [Cool]
Corrupte [Corrupt]
Dagdromende [Daydreaming]
Dansende [Dancing]
Dikke [Fat]
Dode [Dead]
Dunne [Skinny]
Echte [Real]
Effectieve [Effective]
Elektrische [Electronic]
Enorme [Enormous]
Europese [European]
Felle [Bright]
Fictieve [Fictive]
Fietsende [Cycling]
Fluisterende [Whispering]
Fluitende [Whistling]
Gele [Yellow]
Glow-in-the-dark [Glow-in-the-dark]
Grijze [Grey]
Groene [Green]
Grote [Big]
Harige [Hairy]
Harde [Hard]
Homosexuele [Gay]
Horde [Troop of]
Hyperactieve [Hyperactive]
Idiote [Idiotic]
IJzere [Iron]
IJzige [Frosty]
Instelbare [Adjustable]
Ivoren [Ivory]
Jaloerse [Jealous]
Jammerende [Whining]
Japanse [Japanese]
Jokkende [Fibbing]
Jonge [Young]
Kale [Bald]
Kapotte [Broken]
Kleine [Little]
Knappe [Handsome]
Koude [Cold]
Lelijke [Ugly]
Lege [Empty]
Levende [Living]
Lopende [Walking]
Luie [Lazy]
Maffe [Weird]
Massieve [Massive]
Middeleeuwse [Medieval]
Milde [Mellow]
Mythische [Mythical]
Naakte [Naked]
Nachtelijke [Nocturnal]
Nare [Nasty]
Nucleaire [Nuclear]
Normale [Normal]
Ongelovige [Infidel]
Oranje [Orange]
Oude [Old]
Overheerdende [Prevailing]
Oxiderende [Oxidizing]
Paarse [Purple]
Platte [Flat]
Pratende [Talking]
Piraten [Pirate]
Puzzelende [Puzzling]
Quiteense [Female resident of the city of Quito]
Quad-rijdende [ATV-driving]
Quasi [Quasi]
Queue-stotende [(Billiard) cue thumping]
Quiche-etende [Quiche-eating]
Rennende [Running]
Rode [Red]
Romantische [Romantic]
Ronde [Round]
Roze [Pink]
Saaie [Boring]
Schattige [Cute]
Scherpe [Sharp]
Springende [Jumping]
Stoffige [Dusty]
Tongzoenende [French kissing]
Transformerende [Transforming]
Transparente [Transparent]
Treiterende [Tormenting]
Triomferende [Victorious]
Ultieme [Supreme]
Unieke [Unique]
Uniseks [Unisex]
Uiteenlopende [Various]
Uitmuntende [Outstanding]
Vage [Vague]
Verdrietige [Sad]
Vierkante [Square]
Vliegende [Flying]
Vrolijke [Jolly]
Warme [Warm]
Waterige [Aquatic]
Wijze [Wise]
Witte [White]
Wraakzuchtige [Vindicitive]
Xenofobische [Xenophobic]
Xhosa-sprekende [Xhosa-speaking]
XTC-verslaafde [XTC-addicted]
XXX [XXX]
Xylofoonspelende [Xylophone-playing]
Yahoo-zoekende [Yahoe-searching]
Yammerende [Yammering]
Yellende [Cheerleading]
YouTube-streamende [YouTube-streaming]
Youtubende [YouTubing]
Zachte [Soft]
Zingende [Singing]
Zwarte [Black]
Zwemmende [Swimming]
Zwevende [Floating]
```

#### Challenge rules:

- You aren't allowed to use the same random noun twice in one sentence.
- You have to take the license plate input either as string or array/list of characters. You can choose to input without delimiter however, so all these are valid input-formats: `NN-CC-CC`; `NN CC CC`; `NN CCCC`; `NNCCCC`; `N N C C C C`; etc.
- The list of words can be in any reasonable format. Can be three separate lists; maps with the first letters as keys; one or multiple separate text files to read from; all possible. (You are allowed to take the input with or without the English translations added, as long as you output the Dutch sentence.)
- Output can be printing to STDOUT or returning a string.
- The lists above and the resulting sentences will only be in Dutch (with optionally the English translations added behind every word / the entire sentence).
  NOTE: The original idea was to have the lists being part of the code, and *@JonathanAllan* suggested to use just Dutch instead of English, since there are quite a few languages with build-in English libraries. Later in the Sandbox, this switched to having the lists as input, and since I was already halfway through finishing the lists, I kept them Dutch. I've still added the English translations of each word in the list, so you can easily translate what your random output means.
- Because all the nouns are plural, we can assume the numbers will be in the range `02-99`.
- The numbers `02-09` may be outputted with or without leading zero.
- You are allowed to take the input license plate as lowercase instead of uppercase.

#### General rules:

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins.
  Don't let code-golf languages discourage you from posting answers with non-codegolfing languages. Try to come up with an as short as possible answer for 'any' programming language.
- [Standard rules apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/2422#2422) for your answer, so you are allowed to use STDIN/STDOUT, functions/method with the proper parameters and return-type, full programs. Your call.
- [Default Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- If possible, please add a link with a test for your code.
- Also, please add an explanation if necessary.

#### Some possible test cases (but feel free to use your own as well).

```
71-NN-BT
80-XW-IK
13-UU-EF
12-AA-AA
99-ZX-YW
73-TH-QQ
04-DJ-IO
```

What are some of your favorite random sentences?

Comment: Somehow I can't believe those are the lists of words you used to use...

Comment: @Neil As a kid in the past you mean? You're probably right. `X` would always result in something with xylophones, since it was the only word with an `X` I knew as a kid. But when I created this list earlier this week I wanted to have 5 words of each letter for each noun, verb and adjective for the sake of this challenge (which was pretty hard to accomplish for some letters..) Some of those words with a `Q` or `X` I had never even heard of.. And some words would be inappropriate to know as a < 12 y.o. kid. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>37</s>  35 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ṙ2X¤;⁸ṪW¤i’¥Ðḟ"⁹ṫ3¤ŒpŒQẠ$ÐfXK⁹ḣ2¤,K
```

A dyadic link taking a list of lists (of lists of characters): `[[verbs],[adjectives],[nouns]]` on the left and the numberplate (format = `NNCCCC`) on the right and returning a list of characters.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVdLcyO3Ef4rrq1U@bI8xD7kkNOuXpT4EFeiREmuPYAzIAkOZnqCByXxFP8Dl28@xVXeXLJ3125yk8o/RPtHlEZ3Y8RsVU74gMGju9H94Zu1tvb@@fnp8y/fXT18@OuXHz89ff7X7OGD@fL3Xx7@@fjT06d/vPry4@enzx@/f/jwx8/tHz@/e/r3r396/GlxNUjjn3777uHD68Hz8/MPP7x6UxS6Ddrp5tVr7ASzybhuYzdeR5@h98bn8beqqhjo0mmzFGytgI2LxSpwx6wZ7CkfnKzfU0EvwZm8@Z5ugjOLuMx9q0zNCFSxIrSvlhulXCmn7Svedl8vnSpl3b7RDYNb5fwceI8Dq4vgoOmOO8jNhlve6eCutZB3OlRFiNncQxB3Dx9/XzUyFAAPbld5ijNpfoJHAIbBi2FHzqxbQaDbbhQ0n91XRSXA2liYRmb0xcu@try8L4cc1y24fB3HjW9NNvZ419Njh3Zl7MEKPFEYxG@gJRj4iBPdsGsn0Cxp4je1Dqkfu3sfWOA5A6ikZbMGTslA9J7AUM01p8NQKxmCphLAgR@mnRMYyeqRQp941Ug7GZMQjUDSa6xzmox1rDIITtnO7TG4@n@6wSxMIb3TOY7nbD@15vEjgSbMLfBRiD36Lh1XSlJNsO1SeKLF9olVnJETcPLJQRnzae@iKp2xuwGlodjaboZ2kb9jXByNQOg@ou3ZjzOlSlzGx53pshRgGimKs2g4RmdyP@fFykj8EELbZhhl8blVitqQP05TKvIu05c2gzrn7hRcq3N6XzQ78b1oLEg2X7RUnARdl9QXwbzczaV2c9OUGa8lmAgryS2ENYDrptyadT53piTbZloqdGbWWwnGzGkZi45HrrSDO0Zg2v871KPmWtW1HHOd/b822pamWSYIcRrnupdITTHP4FDAoQRv0iUxMmLFDZPCDeQ@0Iz3r5GL57gLEo4mKkbidNasK@otnKnwhjx10J6dXrP0ATsUsVITK8/vU2NVvKV@yufUwpYax@3eSmF1NIEx3opnBAVYRRvtATIFtQ7zlCYi@5Yu8WnJPbRBoKnI0n3gbkQWSWSa3EjtYoHka/RGMxFXyPMeGT31GqxSAtHhVZMVhynSqTXdokNM4HzYoY3yCHXdIPhI08IjC7c90/TCSvdK5SrhXnI80W0jgIzrK4e5woA26UMNXt9F3qsPMnqPSa86g45Lw8uPT7ZoCgPeB4kY@WuueHQDmW0taEf@nUhSldxp5S5P6IHhQWTf1A6U5aaFQKcNLNY5gUZhqRL5Rloy1DldhnrJzUZ2G6YaYhSNJobFC6EW33P2Z2SQC6zW8dZz19KC0X1Y5asaK1UFBule83FjdnQcC6uVYUzMq4lEl9rChgNz6jBRCbDJp0h0K61TUXP/zpRdXCb4zJMpSK3s@8SpfM8T4@RNnMTtNhEUDb9LmaA5molfey6xRP6mvGGijalgIbwsQv96OvfP6AlkCNKkSslhOIP8kfLpXCmKKdIp2smOItaObue8RcbLpYn0uljwjCle8JZqn75MMTJ@kSrB7Y60GFou0SkKrLDz0UC96LoXFrOSiggpWFcCvK58QhQS26UA9uvYZGcvFZmDhIrvkxbzLw3yrnDDpTU623/pIF/6THHVzvAapHxmUmAzw9c1c5gv2yQB@fuVbmAB8xzGqxV41fMt8TNtfzXd62FGeHyMFjTQu7u766UP9xZXAsaju@lrtQLobaFbfL1bU0zVDL9i6DxIHE2dGyUsdfNyUze3SYMQ0HXdDUpFEVurZq7xHWBZjMwx10ztb1pp0NgU/zcxwLeeiLlRjUhjebCQmzW/Gm9FpaJQFm1cahU9oY1RtMFeqhWsMawR6hpXRF@arJZNcJCFr2kwuNFlGbafJ@1DEeuUUtIJkMftwqx58UGvVoZMP0BGSPqGh3WFIXcNfWj@9vgfLBjCW/bzUM1dfuWErYmcs6@HgCW0ftHN5NIRJgAEQljRSEokiK3aMrivMVmyU0exrkUOKw51Imrapg@iHfoAi4ychSVZyFRN4rcEfsKPT3yFKjaseQKqbeRBz4oa81kRL4vhSMsccJbEkXEUYXqCryzvOUha1xMQ0TjAJ3gJ9VyJcBg0WV4NUJ1LLIZa4z@KBG6YCFgQ6tsCamSeUsmFDXEmmzlMsaDDRgrfZJHNIt1HiQEJ5GsfxU4qc2THBs@pMOfImTHIyrHEaZy2d/Mst04LLZl7usx6eZGNOhUJnRiDGXmP7mRitlvO2wmyBhJUUijC2eDDXG8BBZnjCSH9c2Wh7LldLhW@w16iy/o4H4qc/fgxGN/1tlvRxnjXdOiZyLEzvUQmFP/PUphrrPekd6hvPQtisiPRdpsFsUhJRA07fZ7@VnerCuk8S@Oe03eimxd8L1MsVtSunGBTsxZXp@mnJ71sxMQshEWtI2Un9lMvEJnbsIcX52@RwUxBjE6UHKII3EuX@Os2RZc@YhFmIe1Akuky2nw7M2U3ptPLnt2dpZdHQNIuYuAs/VySN1e9XA1XvWLlkkASwkqs3lhVi2ompm52cb6k626L66@2uIblKrpQ4otX5QFUD065r3qy/kZr/ltDsMqVj7idZ4WO9C26@2bybQr8@/fPf/nzePx2@l8)**

#### How?

```
ṙ2X¤;⁸ṪW¤i’¥Ðḟ"⁹ṫ3¤ŒpŒQẠ$ÐfXK⁹ḣ2¤,K - Link: list of lists of lists, words; list, plate
   ¤                                - nilad followed by link(s) as a nilad:
 2                                  -   literal two
  X                                 -   random integer in [1,z] -------- gets 1 or 2
ṙ                                   - rotate left by - words [v,a,n] -> [a,n,v] or [n,v,a]
        ¤                           - nilad followed by link(s) as a nilad:
     ⁸                              -   chain's left argument, words
      Ṫ                             -   tail - get the nouns
       W                            -   wrap in a list
    ;                               - concatenate - add another noun list to the end
                                    - (call this allWordLists) - either [a,n,v,n] or [n,v,a,n])
                  ¤                 - nilad followed by link(s) as a nilad:
               ⁹                    -   chain's right argument, plate
                 3                  -   literal three
                ṫ                   -   tail from index - get the four letters
                                    - (call this letters)
              "                     - zip with the dyadic operation:
            Ðḟ                      -   filter discard if:
           ¥                        -     last two links as a dyad:
         i                          -       first index of (a letter in a word in a wordList in allWordLists)
          ’                         -       decrement (if not found i yields 0, so this result is only 0 when the first index is the head of the list)
                                    - ...this gives us a list of lists of words beginning with the appropriate letters ordered either as [a,v,n,n] or [n,v,a,n]
                   Œp               - Cartesian product of the filtered lists
                         Ðf         - filter keep if:
                        $           -   last two links as a monad:
                     ŒQ             -     distinct sieve (1s at 1st occurrences, 0s elsewhere)
                       Ạ            -     all truthy - i.e. all distinct?
                           X        - random choice from the resulting list - get one four word choice
                            K       - join with spaces
                                ¤   - nilad followed by link(s) as a nilad:
                             ⁹      -   chain's right argument, plate
                               2    -   literal two
                              ḣ     -   head to index - get the two digits
                                 ,  - pair
                                  K - join with a space
```

Answer (score 5):

### [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 89 bytes

**88 bytes code + 1 for `-p`.**

Requires the numberplate to be in the format `## A A A A` and the lists need to be formatted like `("A","B",...)`. If this is pushing the limits of acceptable, please let me know.

```perl
@$_=eval<>for n,v,a;s!\pL!(grep/^$&/,@{(rand>.5?(a,n,v,n):(n,v,a,n))[$-++]})[rand 5]!egi
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVdLcyO3Eb7nV2hdW7FUFuPKYctVeTi2tHqsJFJcihIlOk4K5DSH4GCmJxiAWjGVX@R7Ljnu/4rS6G6M5K1K8YCvAQzQzw/NFrx79/z8w9u//xm2xv3p@xX6veZwe2j@2L35a3v1Zr/00H77t7e//fbwh3/ue9MU3//u3V/2zWHa1Bz8YZ83Ezr46e3gm29@/tfBT2nT3ruf30Bpn5@/@/3eiH5He9Pf7H/1o2kWAK6A5qtDEnyxACu41aEF1yUQA36dwJFpTMNrR9B1AhxCLQh1tBsej00BJnaMttbwAcdrIBOBVjyL1i9jV1jw8oUNHkEueG8b7Ez0Ue95nze9x2Wki0IWAuZ5t7Ib@fhkUBvLqp8UZELQM0@gWiP6hheaf3z@DwRgvBM7T83CW6h476mFIDefumzrKTYhX3GK6pOzQddiYGS9Wa149cyZnYCnuluus1FnsRYfnRsjrj7HWo45x6bQGVxl5B2WrOGHwqJY/KFAJ@CiqxwptJENzsXOCqxb8NYQujCq@AVW4vALbEoHUXD0YupFfAQ589IsxBOXJgSdiY8l1gvjdEeDrWTHJTbZF1cA3QLVcSTQeYJK8Eusa8pAowG7op2i5lXyBV82NKYUi4emkROH0Ijmwxz2YZRxBFE8O7J0T0U5x8aMUL8cqZ9G6Xi/QC8nXy9BM/e6lMHZVVbq2utQ6Z7xMcdkbHc7ydsxOhssmDIn3hi7sIAd@lLuH2NwKFd9jKboZCxLUyPFwOkC@OjypR@j/fxLsF0v7cSuiaFY86UTI8kyodLtQO2fJDfXZrm2DbtxQj6kBKOgsB43yzVIfG6cqaqMGjH6JkD5q6q6CajKTQcePgkyK4nLlIq1wlYSbGo3auoUt9AYw/hWsvjWyiG3jd3SJvMCbQArFt7eHA26YJdV@u7OWShDtKLWnSd7wmPyLi9SEWox3HnUZLqLLkdnZtzWqgEz6MTcGfo6A/KpUwVJCmLN/SBXw/1gufZUd50S1j002DhTy0H3Tw5X2LzGOUgP/REPXxzxgOU6@lAQ2VZ5wjjwxn8h6fdzgM@/KFjnyifcUv2JK@ePau18Pv46Of4gMfZyCW3QivhxGZKLBddt7Ofr2GXYdUl3EY5yPhxB4UFdf5TvO4KtjxSFTOFBObwLPrOzSdnjbT78mGrB21Uss@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@pMgpXmFsEa8@NLwqPd5HtnpudurdCZ3ezUGTOvbcQs@lLZ2aM8TPdo2/87NRCiNenVF5jtf7DU49qmZB6O07iAQSI1k5k7BpoS/i01aea5C5wLKcxzczOXTo65eEGnEOEAUzERp3d2U7G08raiCHUskD6vpKbsAgnssQKYlRdP3EZTowXST/ORR7jjwct4vDZUHU0QnN5@QbhEZ/igYySm4NFTnvJGYt/CJz4tREo9lUBbsabvUcRILJLINJmRRupi6XGBLQgRV8Tz1GSw1KR3NoHoKdSsxWnyNLfM/UfaPfPppy7qI9SLQfEZ8IdnDh8HthmENQwK4yvlXjb8jP8RCGDlzo2nXBHAh6QWuoNPUc46R519oqQ3vULSQHPbvCNVBMg5RMTEXwsjs1vMbEt/bDzbd6FJVYjQaiwv@IGRSWJf4G7ZyUD/CPi2S0d1zqAxVKpMvpE/uYKcLqlN5mGrp12lGhIULTDDUkB4pPdc7Bla4gKXWu1ORMcfDJ/COodqZEwVBKS45utGYugoLul/mBXMzAtMoiU43Ipjrqmb2TAQla@J6NL/t0K1u/5ki94v49RwgVCr2D72Jsd5bL2@ieNIba7T6Y8pE0C8mfh14BNL5DXTWSHamAoWw8tHZN8AsjzhJ1Ag6pAqJbthgnmR8@km/fMSOiU9xdDUNHuOzk1LjJdLk@h1tZIdUwrwjmufV6bkmW6VKsG/nmlTuxdEBBteLVqsV7146ygruYiIgqFS0EElHXVyietTgOQ6NtnYO8PqEKHS@wSq/h39R6qUG7ixzps95qDPjFTtjMKg5TPTAptZCdfMU77sUgso66krXuEiu/F@TX8c6K8u8zMffz89HqQWnx6jlUzc3/c9M5I3@jg/GPrbPdhh/@nD64oSohb4BT/nSWZoFuZGOWr@Eidqlb3MPUJd95NaTwf/xTZY0ud50P4P)

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>124</s> <s>120</s> 118 bytes

Takes input in currying syntax `(s)(a)` where ***s*** is a string in `"NNCCCC"` format and ***a*** is the array of arrays of words `[nouns, verbs, adj]`.

```js
s=>a=>s.replace(/\D/g,c=>' '+(g=a=>a.sort(R)[0][0]==c?a.shift(i/=4):g(a))(a[i&3]),i=(R=_=>Math.random()-.5)()<0?18:36)
```

#### Test cases

```js
let f =

s=>a=>s.replace(/\D/g,c=>' '+(g=a=>a.sort(R)[0][0]==c?a.shift(i/=4):g(a))(a[i&3]),i=(R=_=>Math.random()-.5)()<0?18:36)

const NOUNS = ["Aanbeelden","Aardbeien","Apen","Appels","Auto's","Bananen","Bessen","Bloemen","Bomen","Bijen","Cadeaus","Cavia's","Cheerleaders","Circusdieren","Citroenen","Dinosaurussen","Dieren","Documenten","Doctoren","Dolfijnen","E-mails","Edelstenen","Eekhoorns","Enqûetes","Ezels","Fabrieken","Fietsen","Flessen","Fontijnen","Foto's","G-spots","Giraffen","Glazen","Gymschoenen","Gummen","Haaien","Homo's","Honden","Hoofden","Horloges","Idioten","Idolen","IJsklontjes","Illusies","Imperia","Jassen","Jokers","Jongleurs","Jurken","Juwelen","Kabels","Katten","Kauwgomballen","Knoppen","Konijnen","Leesboeken","Leeuwen","Legercommandanten","Lesbies","Lummels","Maagden","Mannen","Mensen","Mieren","Muren","Neuzen","Nieuwkomers","Nonnen","Noten","Nummerborden","Oceanen","Ogen","Olifanten","Oren","Orkanen","PC's","Pizza's","Politieagenten","Postbezorgers","Potloden","Quads","Quaggamosselen","Querulanten","Quiëtisten","Quizzen","Radio's","Ramen","Regiseuren","Rekenmachines","Relschoppers","Schepen","Slakken","Slangen","Stegosaurussen","Stoelen","T-rexen","Tafels","Theekopjes","Tijgers","Tovenaars","Uien","Uilen","Universa","Universiteiten","USB-sticks","Vliegtuigen","Vrachtwagens","Vrienden","Vrouwen","Vulkanen","Walvissen","Wespen","Wormen","Worstelaars","Wortels","X-assen","X-chromosomen","Xenonlampen","Xylofonen","Xylofonisten","Y-assen","Y-chromosomen","Yoghurtdranken","Yogaleraren","Yogaleraressen","Zeeën","Zeehonden","Zeepbellen","Zwanen","ZZP'ers"];
const VERBS = ["Accepteren","Activeren","Amputeren","Amuseren","Assisteren","Bakken","Bedreigen","Bellen","Bevruchten","Bijten","Castreren","Categoriseren","Centrifugeren","Claimen","Coachen","Dagvaardigen","Daten","Degraderen","Dienen","Dwarsbomen","Electroniseren","Eren","Erven","Eten","Exploderen","Factureren","Fokken","Föhnen","Fotographeren","Frituren","Gooien","Graderen","Grijpen","Groeperen","Groeten","Hacken","Hallucineren","Haten","Helpen","Huren","Importeren","Inspireren","Intelligente","Irriteren","Isoleren","Jagen op","Jatten","Jennen","Jongleren met","Justeren","Klonen","Koken","Kopen","Kraken","Kussen","Labelen","Leasen","Lonken","Loven","Lusten","Maken","Martelen","Merken","Meten","Mollen","Negeren","Neuken","Neutraliseren","Normaliseren","Notificeren","Observeren","Oliën","Ontbloten","Ontsmetten","Ordenen","Penetreren","Pesten","Plagen","Porren","Produceren","Quadrilleren met","Quadrupleren","Queruleren over","Quoteren","Quotiseren","Raadplegen","Redden","Reinigen","Ruilen","Roken","Schieten","Schoppen","Schudden","Slaan","Stoppen","Tackelen","Telen","Tellen","Temperen","Torpederen","Unificeren","Unlocken","Upgraden","Urineren","Utiliseren","Verbinden","Verjagen","Verkopen","Vermoorden","Verwijderen","Wassen","Wekken","Wijzigen","Wreken","Wurgen","Xeroxen","Xoipen","Xeroxen","Xoipen","X-en","Yammeren","Yellen","Yielding","YouTube-streamen","Youtuben","Zegenen","Zieken","Zien","Zoeken","Zoenen"];
const ADJECTIVES = ["Abstracte","Achterlijke","Afrikaanse","Amerikaanse","Angstaanjagende","Baby","Blauwe","Blote","Boze","Broze","Charmante","Chinese","Chocolade","Coole","Corrupte","Dagdromende","Dansende","Dikke","Dode","Dunne","Echte","Effectieve","Elektrische","Enorme","Europese","Felle","Fictieve","Fietsende","Fluisterende","Fluitende","Gele","Glow-in-the-dark","Grijze","Groene","Grote","Harige","Harde","Homosexuele","Horde","Hyperactieve","Idiote","IJzere","IJzige","Instelbare","Ivoren","Jaloerse","Jammerende","Japanse","Jokkende","Jonge","Kale","Kapotte","Kleine","Knappe","Koude","Lelijke","Lege","Levende","Lopende","Luie","Maffe","Massieve","Middeleeuwse","Milde","Mythische","Naakte","Nachtelijke","Nare","Nucleaire","Normale","Ongelovige","Oranje","Oude","Overheerdende","Oxiderende","Paarse","Platte","Pratende","Piraten","Puzzelende","Quiteense","Quad-rijdende","Quasi","Queue-stotende","Quiche-etende","Rennende","Rode","Romantische","Ronde","Roze","Saaie","Schattige","Scherpe","Springende","Stoffige","Tongzoenende","Transformerende","Transparente","Treiterende","Triomferende","Ultieme","Unieke","Uniseks","Uiteenlopende","Uitmuntende","Vage","Verdrietige","Vierkante","Vliegende","Vrolijke","Warme","Waterige","Wijze","Witte","Wraakzuchtige","Xenofobische","Xhosa-sprekende","XTC-verslaafde","XXX","Xylofoonspelende","Yahoo-zoekende","Yammerende","Yellende","YouTube-streamende","Youtubende","Zachte","Zingende","Zwarte","Zwemmende","Zwevende"];

console.log(f("71NNBT")([NOUNS, VERBS, ADJECTIVES]))
console.log(f("80XWIK")([NOUNS, VERBS, ADJECTIVES]))
console.log(f("13UUEF")([NOUNS, VERBS, ADJECTIVES]))
console.log(f("12AAAA")([NOUNS, VERBS, ADJECTIVES]))
console.log(f("99ZXYW")([NOUNS, VERBS, ADJECTIVES]))
console.log(f("73THQQ")([NOUNS, VERBS, ADJECTIVES]))
console.log(f("04DJIO")([NOUNS, VERBS, ADJECTIVES]))
```

#### How?

The sequences of lists to pick the words from are stored as bitmasks, in reverse order:

```
Noun, Verb, Adjective, Noun --> 0, 1, 2, 0 --> 00 01 10 00 --[reverse]--> 00100100 --> 36
Adjective, Noun, Verb, Noun --> 2, 0, 1, 0 --> 10 00 01 00 --[reverse]--> 00010010 --> 18
```

That's why ***i*** is randomly initialized to either ***18*** or ***36***.

```js
s => a =>                           // given 's' and 'a'
  s.replace(                        // replace in 's'
    /\D/g, c =>                     // each non-digit character 'c' with:
    ' ' + (                         // a space followed by
      g = a =>                      // a word picked from the list 'a'
        a.sort(R)                   //   shuffle the list
        [0][0] == c ?               //   if the 1st char. of the 1st word is matching 'c':
          a.shift(i /= 4)           //     return this word (removing it from the list)
                                    //     and discard the 2 least significant bits of 'i'
        :                           //   else:
          g(a)                      //     try again with a recursive call
    )(a[i & 3]),                    // initial call to g() with the next list
    i = (                           // initialize 'i', using:
      R = _ => Math.random() - 0.5  //   R(): returns a random float in [-0,5, 0.5)
    )() < 0 ? 18 : 36               // to either 18 or 36 (see above)
  )                                 // end of replace()
```

Answer (score 3):

## Excel, <s>382</s> 353 bytes

```
=D1&E1&" "&IF(RAND()>0.5,INDIRECT("C"&INT((CODE(F1)-64.8+RAND())*5))&" "&INDIRECT("A"&INT((CODE(G1)-64.8+RAND())*5))&" "&INDIRECT("B"&INT((CODE(H1)-64.8+RAND())*5)),INDIRECT("A"&INT((CODE(F1)-64.8+RAND())*5))&" "&INDIRECT("B"&INT((CODE(G1)-64.8+RAND())*5))&" "&INDIRECT("C"&INT((CODE(H1)-64.8+RAND())*5)))&" "&INDIRECT("A"&INT((CODE(I1)-64.8+RAND())*5))
```

Three lists in `A`, `B` and `C` respectively.  Numberplate characters in `D1` -to- `I1`.  Formula in any other cell.

Golfing:

- Last word will always be `NOUN`,
- -14 bytes replacing `ADDRESS` with `"A"&INT()`
- -14 bytes arithmetic`(CODE(F1)-65)*5+RAND()*5+1` with `(CODE(F1)-64.8+RAND())*5`

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), <s>535</s> <s>314</s> <s>304</s> <s>297</s> 382 bytes

```java
import java.util.*;
L->N->V->A->{int c=((int)(Math.random()*8))%2,i=0,f;String[]a=new String[4],b[]={A,N,V,N,N,V,A,N};for(;i<4;i++){List<String>p=new ArrayList();for(f=0;f<b[i+c*4].length;f++)if(b[i+c*4][f].charAt(0)==L.charAt(i+2)&&(i<3|!b[i+c*4][f].equals(a[1-c])))p.add(b[i+c*4][f]);a[i]=p.get((int)(Math.random()*p.size()));}System.out.print(L.substring(0,2)+" "+L.join(" ",a));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVhZbxs5En4e/wqtgZ2RYreQyWaBHSg2EDu@JVnxJR/wA9XNblHNJnvYpGwr61807/uyj/lh2SKr2PZksgYSVhWvOj9Wa8GWLNE1V4us/CaqWhvbWYCs76yQ/dyp1Aqt@m8Ga3@ZBNla7WZSpJ1UsqbpjJhQnS9rHfhrLLMg36f9H86tEarY/F5wd/9D0a5Wjau4aUXb8NcpOludb8Nke5xsXyXbH5PtL0LZTrrV7cLY646YnfcNU5muur03/@r1/v5uU2y93cwH8RS2pfhDh7j395uzu/utLx83x5tX8M//D/TzINemOxAf3g/Exkbvy1A0ltTYrsP@j8awJy/u9sLafOvtIP8wuxMb6Zv3933JVWHngxw2i7wbxXf5fT@dM/PRdt/2traGkREb73o//9wVH/7x77@9Xst/d0w2XXb3a5Le93q9us@y7PVpvQG7E/dbdb/g9ocOqPuNWPEu7B08nz81lld97Wy/Bktsd9hv3KwJVnXfbr7rbax31jeG/YUWqgvkJvO7vkF8QzApyBTTpRZZp4JQd6NfO6xHYfd/rVRppxqI2Sun339Z/8jUjHOZcbW@CYzJZlwgXdNQc9l4wln9iyd2mGIqzO3wpkFCal4hpWkUizDusowz1wRqKVg4YHfOuZEcZkxghUldkwlucIewRnO84JNQumHOOLrnU1z0SaeQkMpGxuool7lY4Oa9BLwSVN/LwARLZ@7xcq61UWFC/f71v9zyQK/Qzn02M4KXYe2@4BZv3pfR1n2tbLxiX5NPDpKm1jZQwrA8D7MHkq2QeKqadB6NOnAV@uiQMXT1oa7wmEOtMpLoPFJG6iJoeJQJjRYfZVoicdyUEhRa4AIpXSOQrGpuBAPqmJHix7pEhx9rVUjukHYGTT12DxzPPGEz9MQJs5Yk7qHQ1YxJWqF0jdlxolX0xZDzZqbJccDAeUgV3KS6qqAQGAVsCCtRzaH3RbhsxFiBFo@YwhNHXKHmoxj2kcNxzB16dizgnhJyLhgz1rRzTH4a@@PNTBs8@TTllLmnBQ5S5FGpU0NDSWsmuyEmE7FaYd5OtBRWcFbExJvoxs74SpsC759oKzVe9dmxrMGxKFilIQaSJrhxMl762Ymvf1jRtNwK7TpjEOtw6RnDZDnjhWg42X/m3VyxdC5UcOMZ@BASDIIS9DhP5xzjcy5ZWUZKodHnlhd/qqpzq0m5i8TwR6RYjnG5gGItdY0JdiEWZOqFXnLFWKAvMYsvBR5yqcQSFrEXUlgu0MLL852kAdQq/b4rKXhhnUC1rgzYYx@8d8MkFCEVw5XRlExXTsboTJlcCjJgyhs0d6pNFQnwqSQFgbNozXUSq@E6SecG6q4hwLrmSivJKjzo@knqXKvXdAzSTXvEzXdH3Ohi7ozNAPPLKGCSG2a@42j/Ledf/yBiHisf6BrqD115@0DW3t5OfvGOfx78FdfBw7Mf4Hqa8tpS3XyEF30Z6ap2rbxyTSSbxluIzE7Mmh2eGU4B2ola7fClcRCrCPSWkB4esIjhzOeYEfHwXagYI3JXRF4ygT7b1RB1hG5WLCFeGd32iRG488L4lyLiPz0MDxDZGfl9T/IU3gzVXrcXhyWOeNLeY@2rE@f2WWpdVHdfk7n7X/8zf0F2uLiexyVGWCq@A60x4Q9eFDswYlETpaH2TEtbgvq0JAIwOoWyNcTSPJe4/ZAuOQrdHa06Uk0torJHry09MqBXpBt4FJA89lXU0XUgCcSPOYEjwj8s7FTcBuRv434iKedPdEkj4bxhJIigMfSvBKE5I5GmvB9qdPzQUc2MaPeI@UIkcKeHZ0QuGmlKrzGPaQIwX0bCGiZbs8dQ539irchFStzpDOQx2wHhscZOlZ1JehaAbsD2iPsZJdUExjaFJ5x0n0hWENobmjI6c/E2D/RGyNcODSJXy3aFR/wwD34xQaJtOwm6RzvOGMtgW0EYn2VECEVFceYIY88oPoD0gvx3jg8AkY42A@wzwniavPCpSHD/Mkaiirl7oU3NY3oDjr/491JJTdl8WYfiDKRpk/oSvkZam64AnUQEcm4W5EwgS8otICsdn2hgHsQi3jtlLcJThU7FYkXOmBpqNqbOFIThRuPzda1F/X9FCcIx870BktH@GwGdMABoQGt34WY88aDGIr47CyJE6YKS5jb2ircICrexBbrFfu9HiM2yBQ@I/APY9p8BgE08oDZgrJFiUQYuN6KEYDaBAdVfcaqAjwGmgnMzHgB89hT6cujcODbo4cgdvQqDwXEXvnoq34sE2jcTSOlUSxYO2tUAKmE0kNJhIQB1Zjz0Zsj5Jg1JUQZNP2lkHQCOx11vhh@hLQar@ZIjZpdgNHQtgVP@4faEM5AVQYt9H5TQg7ebqB0Pp@9LR@9Vy1qiD3jYeCD1QyJUYuc8yZgpCaaD4QfhEwOJoNwhM5BWSIRDfE/e8EeHZx1qkj5BfbBWIezIQx@@AlWQwHMAswHqZgylSx2BGb6UTLDvmPIvQ6amWB6HtwiFANQ8tN8SB/jECLedSICEQCgGVR1w2oUtQx7TxffdYVjSaUNfbkg5wQMYQ0DCCE8/2jMSABvS9@4NsjJsGD3ZeQzVmLHSIuHjGq8bo6Fjl8KHnUA6gDQPeFtwqZfomFNojxaBQJVPARP9B2FG2p0@iqz1y8R3cBxRGG2fGBbjPBGGns@Jg75ZkvizzwSO3vRQnBgPKHGONQIx2fna1vZlE9iX8MifhdcSSU2Dr5TohjMdJ0M@nftPOURe0BMN9V24CdE591/5sTQBifMcV1xAgFcBJsLMBXimyX0lmNeS2vePFlku7KtJoau8ZS8lZGUoIkBrXhLR8BJbdO8S2aYA8JVT0dgrFtQB7IWnjJP6V/DRVRI2hE49LjY6Bn3KsGqnEAYqnykV2FRguKYG8mXlu0Wc9212rmfRjddz@BKBb@cA5eH464vdxH8zwLuVB0Hy@PiYtG24Bn@0kb5h8CWfrHS7@eZ1TSGqI/kdmEdhgPPA3DJCqduXSEH3bVD2wKuqFVJFAbC3yO5/d/I/fomtt4OO@PBP/7//tWrtp7ii6EOlyqfu@m@/jeFvvUd8@FEmMqGTBya07t2XV6I3WPvpp@9/NJKq6@XPQYnntedv/wM)

Comment: You can still golf some more things: `L->N->V->A->` can be `(L,N,V,A)->`; `int j=i` can be `j=i` when you add `,j` to the other ints; the space `j< 3` can be removed; some of those `||` can be `|` and `&&` can be `&`; `(c<0?!s.equals(a[1]):!s.equals(a[0]))` can be `!s.equals(c<0?a[1]:a[0])`. Apart from that it looks like a great answer now that it's golfed from 535 to 314. :)

Comment: @Giuseppe I've fixed the previous problem but I can't deal with -xxx-, it's non-competing now

Comment: It seems to work now after your last edit. :) Now that it's working, let's get to some more golfing: [TryItOnline: **365 bytes**](https://tinyurl.com/y949d2cu). Short summary of the changes: `int` variables inside for-loop; `ArrayList` to `Stack`; `L->N->V->A->` to `(L,N,V,A)->`; removed parenthesis around `(int)(Math.random()*8)`; Added `int t` to replace 4x `i+c*4`; `&&` to `&`.

Comment: Love heart code <3

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 82 bytes

```python
def f(l,d):print(l[:2],*map(lambda i,j:d[i][j].pop(),{'anvn','nvan'}.pop(),l[2:]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZhLcxs5DoDv/hUqX2RvWVuTZKuy46o9xG9bfsiybNlOpbYoNdSimiJ72KQcayq/aO572WN@WBYkAaq1OcTgCw0CID5S9bubG/3p168CZp3Znjoo9g9rK7XbU18PP347@NtS1HtKLCeF6MiDxWHxVX77uvj299rUe/sHf3aFXunuQVevhO7@oF719ePht/39X9p43XT@1fmz@6V7GP4XegKgCsAVHWzZYgIyNna/eGe6zW7ormm4rkE13R8oHsXVR9A0aehILkgwSxKEFppEZSD0hoXHceHxHMAqEAXYJsw4Rkn4IO4ei5UU6bvH0k59U0iwSc@xdNaAJk0nUdOJmXrU7dKMkzz3xKiZXGhuTJ3hAalNI7z10fSg6DQqOi1wbw5oxan@4@d/wUG07nQdth0EqObGWJ0avaWQ5I6zqOJMgiN/nBnt@PO7Z4Y9eSYmVkJFcxRkG86jgnMl1mns3C/Jj@fvy2Y6N2TY7rmv6/ek7FxaMZuRgouo4EKIFL3uhTGzgkWdJatMGTe1e2GWwaiw9jKuvbxqKoVmL9KmL5c1WIxEEAujkoLLQhpy9aVSvpGQ9n8VNVwZXSrwKaRX/g1o1ZXgNLkyFfCwrcj0flzcF44094V/K81yIhSt72tTUwr2jc5R7YsJp@N1VHEdnJYidQ0l2KlZLoUuBGfHNTQTCTSOsuFIYAutTdbcRFU3QtNXbjwlzo0QJfnxJqfZDWgO4W1ceGt44a1EpRUeh7ThW/AU21t24W2w106MLUjFXVRxZys@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@O8bzaeXMl3maCIlv5cYWouAbRnjCLj8R5QpDXrARSEUGIZQ2QJfnuW0E0g5OafxUwRSJq@lzcWRFwvc6VBO2gvhnpeNzfSamQebWz//MNZORPRKwiObU86yGKGgMQewccV@zjvOW5WHAsSgX9TYEQdFJuBCOhSl99IINvEC8@CkWJf44UXBZh@NDky51U8u8i0uLG8yNBqGYB7KTWjTMQEtcxNHOElyC3ybproCBcRXKQcfUbSgqPnh9QxvoW8FSLn59wx4gEBoK07XRjDjPB/w6YJO5J5pt7Blm7o0IRYQh57iz4p5Mb8aeXQq1SRRknJzJaW6Cd3ZrHMrWWLXNP@0mihl5F@BI4gSX56OLsxp0p8tgDMc/o7A7AN7vANdvDtpACToVA2sKny0cGMvhYwSKwkq1FbfEwtiDHrapy@RQBnmzxajA1yqnBfOwKJh4UvMRHXJ4h56RMRSiwNVc74mBCZHMOc@6EHSCyNgel@C26Qcc35GxNeTzNIJlvZF5Sjg0XLOIfZYOTOipYy1h5rWi/aiV4fP26KRqHQ3CH9ZkmSEH9k0usinYXHCIUK5MneWl2VyVCH8ZHWNvSwYhF5ixXKzZwWML1Tb3wBq6CDwbWTPetmFmvPMTYpMIlzWSJT6ZpC4Ts/wI5/RCMee7zMum1kd@dV/5/h6kiolV5s78JniVhC1RLCCSaotdaIGsMNINRCjpsnHYiv4qUtdsa8IErcJCnBqBUFbJRQVtioWTlh5u6/RX4fU7SWLyHv/aMNR@vJmpUSJ98NhgGYzCXGAJ0I56LaY@yfHmB21a4UXaBlglFSeG/gazuU9iEKPgsTy2GRV2QXCqEI54Z0xNfAmhv2CVWt5i3iQnnOpwR2pjKkQnPcA80T999ExuNNBbrsgTXWy0KAVJSeDPGhhKmqVk5Lkybz2pe24OvULYqk2pdzxxYvPBi5DbCUwWk5Yk6goXKvjuwyfbD7Y12h75s@LXbXqgRelqTWoQYljKJ3jf2qJTzVlyJfB9bkmOdC6oP2U8tRBi0EaTFlho0jtM0d/auPTxvvFpVV9hkYOtN5oEfqAlQtX8hWtIyRnFVXY3kendzXOwbyTWPRUebQ21VVJxg/WAHXoTHsdtRAlRJetu/VSBkMl3iVxJDJfyjRG37DHGUgnKrMipd99lsXHOHdIg/KRR5A68wi6S5GkfxKVwFwciEXlrgA95hpXHd5diLYPYT@vzy8wBUOQCYno2FE9agKPooh64TQf4UJtMq0c0cotH4f6RxoZUA4YmnOTs7qHJ42QLwSj8KpVLz0P47YEQNJuRm8JbzNYs4oYlJRHxCN3UzML5zK4cWWmWs3Ybp9ThseCoDbJ1ZkeYlutYXck0AlW4j9ELTeEZW0J6hbml19kVOAkqHkCnKsrFFqjwoV9xUXsSaU/xJcY68OWWEwYRhVcGyHtkRtn09bGkeI@5Yowt5uQ6PB3IXWOMt@XlxKnRcS@8JxHws/TJ5@dnfn/NzCRH6XmOL@JeU0fQ0cz4dDPoP8qpLbRtYSstSOAiWcyN6a3NRt3LVkFgOJJaAt1buDdGkgmu1K9vsMxfwMYqy5w9AXhFKL5GC/segadRXfyxEuetUI7POJQFyhs24jrMns6/O1J3bPgBYO/z/mFntic1vt329g86G637vz5/uL09Gu3887fn8WV/58Onx8fTs50PH7/gv53ff399fhnvfP40uri/3/ntHydXl3f/Aw)

Function taking a string `l` for the license plate and a dictionary `d` containing dictionaries with nouns, verbs and adjectives. These must be labeled `'n'`, `'v'` and `'a'`, respectively.

In each of these dictionaries, the words are grouped and labeled by their first letter. Each key then contains a `set` of words. By using the `set.pop()` method to generate output, the chosen words are both random and non-duplicate.

Comment: Oh, I like the `set.pop()` approach! Very nice. :) I'm not entirely sure if the input method of the lists you've used is valid according to the meta though. It now looks like a snipper instead of program/function taking the lists as input(s)/argument(s). Regardless, nice answer.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen You are right concerning the input, this is indeed just a snippet. I'll update my code.

Answer (score 0):

## [C#](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/), 245 bytes

```
Random r=new Random();var a1=a[r.Next(0,a.Length)];var n1=n[r.Next(0,n.Length)];var n2=n[r.Next(0,n.Length)];var v1=v[r.Next(0,v.Length)];var m=r.Next(0,2)==0;Console.WriteLine($"{r.Next(0,10)}{r.Next(0,10)} {m?a1:n1} {m?n1:v1} {m?v1:a1} {n2}");
```

Surely not the shortest but it was fun to do so idc xD

Same code uncompacted (272 bytes):

```
Random r=new Random();
var a1 = a[r.Next(0, a.Length)];
var n1 = n[r.Next(0, n.Length)];
var n2 = n[r.Next(0, n.Length)];
var v1 = v[r.Next(0, v.Length)];
var m = r.Next(0, 2)==0;
Console.WriteLine($"{r.Next(0,10)}{r.Next(0,10)} {m?a1:n1} {m?n1:v1} {m?v1:a1} {n2}");
```

Comment: Currently is not a full program. Will do that tomorrow